# Getting the contents of a library interactively in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis, ess

Is there an equivalent of dir function (python) in R?

When I load a library in R like -

> library(vrtest)

I want to know all the functions that are in that library.

In Python, dir(vrtest) would be a list of all attributes of vrtest.

I guess in general, I am looking for the best way to get help on R while running it in ESS on linux. I see all these man pages for the packages I have installed, but I am not sure how I can access them.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`help(package = packagename)` will list all non-internal functions in a package.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, use `ls()`.

You can use search() to see what's in the search path:

```
> search() 
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics"
[4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets"
[7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

You can search a particular package with the full name:

```
 > ls("package:graphics")
 [1] "abline"          "arrows"          "assocplot"       "axis"
 ....
```

I also suggest [that you look **at this related question** on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386767/are-there-any-good-r-object-browsers) which includes some more creative approaching to browsing the environment.  If you're using ESS, then you can use Ess-rdired.

To get the help pages on a particular topic, you can either use `help(function.name)` or `?function.name`.  You will also find the `help.search()` function useful if you don't know the exact function name or package.  And lastly, [have a look at the **sos** package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sos/).

Comment: Thanks. I guess search() followed by ls("package:vrtest") is the way to do it.

Comment: You can also just provide the numeric position of the package in ls().  For the example of the graphics package, you could have done ls(3)

Answer (score 1):

```
help(topic) #for documentation on a topic
?topic

summary(mydata) #an overview of data objects try

ls() # lists all objects in the local namespace

str(object) # structure of an object
ls.str() # structure of each object returned by ls()

apropos("mytopic") # string search of the documentation
```

---

All from the [R reference card](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! R reference card is a great resource.