# Determining memory usage of objects?

Tags: memory, r

I'd like to work out how much RAM is being used by each of my objects inside my current workspace. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: In addition to all answer, I would like to refer reading memory management from Advanced R: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4827843/1870254) from a different but related question, in contrast to answers here, gives sorted AND human readable output.

Answer (score 263):

some time ago I stole this little nugget from [here](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e6/help/09/01/1121.html):

```
sort( sapply(ls(),function(x){object.size(get(x))}))
```

it has served me well

Comment: also, if one wants the total memory used by an R session, one can do `object.size(x=lapply(ls(), get))` and `print(object.size(x=lapply(ls(), get)), units="Mb")`

Comment: That nice little nugged misled me, since I had something big called 'x' (hint: it looked small); here's an replacement: `sort( sapply(mget(ls()),object.size) )` .

Comment: @tflutre My understanding is that this sort of thing can be misleading as R is copy on write. If I take some_list <- some_other_list, the size of some_list is reported as the same size as some_other_list, but if I only read from some_list then the memory is being shared. Can someone confirm if this is correct?

Comment: @savagent I don't know enough about R to answer with certainty, but you may well be right. In that case, maybe `memory.profile()` advocated by @doug below is a better solution? You can't distinguish per object anymore, though.

Comment: you can also use `format` to get human readable sizes: `sort(sapply(ls(), function(x) format(object.size(get(x)), unit = 'auto')))`

Comment: Just wanted to note (I know this is old) that you can use `eval` to create this code as a function, set the 2nd argument to `parent.frame()` and just feed `ls()` into the overall function.

Comment: @savagent that's right, according to http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html

Comment: Isn't there a more efficient solution that doesn't make a copy of all the objects in ls() in order to get memory usage, which `get()` seems to be doing here?

Comment: I think using `magrittr` is a little cleaner. Can do 
    `Mb <- ls() %>% sapply(. %>% get %>% object.size %>% '/'(10^6))` then `cbind(Mb, "Mb") %>% as.data.frame`

Comment: Same same, but slightly different. It is also possible to modify/mask normal print.object_size with this oneliner
`print.object_size = function(x) utils:::print.object_size(x,units="Mb") `
If this defined function is in scope, then object.size will output in unit Mb always

Comment: As mentioned by @savagent and also confirmed by Dzmitry Lazerka, utils::object.size() indeed does _not_ account for shared references and can return too big sizes. As Hadley Wickham suggests, use lobstr::obj_size() instead which accounts for shared references.

Comment: More readable `sort(sapply(ls(), function(x) object.size(get(x)))) |> stack()`

Answer (score 62):

**1. *by object size***

to get memory allocation on an *object-by-object* basis, call **object.size()** and pass in the object of interest:

```
object.size(My_Data_Frame)
```

(unless the argument passed in is a variable, it must be quoted, or else wrapped in a *get* call.)variable name, then omit the quotes,

you can loop through your namespace and get the size of all of the objects in it, like so:

```
for (itm in ls()) { 
    print(formatC(c(itm, object.size(get(itm))), 
        format="d", 
        big.mark=",", 
        width=30), 
        quote=F)
}
```

**2. *by object type***

to get memory usage for your namespace, by object type, use **memory.profile()**

```
memory.profile()

   NULL      symbol    pairlist     closure environment     promise    language 
      1        9434      183964        4125        1359        6963       49425 
special     builtin        char     logical     integer      double     complex 
    173        1562       20652        7383       13212        4137           1
```

(There's another function, *memory.size()* but i have heard and read that it only seems to work on Windows. It just returns a value in MB; so to get max memory used at any time in the session, use memory.size(max=T)).

Comment: Useful to print in a human readable way: `print(object.size(my_object), units = "auto")` or `format(object.size(my_object), units = "auto")`

Comment: "`memory.size()` is no longer supported." R version 4.3.1, Windows 11, March 2024.

Answer (score 24):

You could try the `lsos()` function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session):

```
R> a <- rnorm(100)
R> b <- LETTERS
R> lsos()
       Type Size Rows Columns
b character 1496   26      NA
a   numeric  840  100      NA
R>
```

Answer (score 19):

This question was posted and got legitimate answers so much ago, but I want to let you know another useful tips to get the size of an object using a library called [gdata](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdata/index.html) and its `ll()` function.

```
library(gdata)
ll() # return a dataframe that consists of a variable name as rownames, and class and size (in KB) as columns
subset(ll(), KB > 1000) # list of object that have over 1000 KB
ll()[order(ll()$KB),] # sort by the size (ascending)
```

Comment: The third line can be easily sorted with dplyr like so: subset(ll(), KB > 1000) %>% arrange(desc(KB))

Answer (score 4):

another (slightly prettier) option using `dplyr`

```
    data.frame('object' = ls()) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(size_unit = object %>%sapply(. %>% get() %>% object.size %>% format(., unit = 'auto')),
                    size = as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(size_unit, split = ' '), FUN = function(x) x[1])),
                    unit = factor(sapply(strsplit(size_unit, split = ' '), FUN = function(x) x[2]), levels = c('Gb', 'Mb', 'Kb', 'bytes'))) %>% 
      dplyr::arrange(unit, dplyr::desc(size)) %>% 
      dplyr::select(-size_unit)
```

Answer (score 2):

A data.table function that separates memory and unit for easier sorting:

```
    ls.obj <- {as.data.table(sapply(ls(),
    function(x){format(object.size(get(x)),
    nsmall=3,digits=3,unit="Mb")}),keep.rownames=TRUE)[,
    c("mem","unit") := tstrsplit(V2, " ", fixed=TRUE)][,
    setnames(.SD,"V1","obj")][,.(obj,mem=as.numeric(mem),unit)][order(-mem)]}
```

> ls.obj
>
> ```
>                        obj     mem unit
>     1:                obj1 848.283   Mb
>     2:                obj2  37.705   Mb
> ```

...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse`-based function to calculate the size of all objects in your environment:

```
weigh_environment <- function(env){
  
  purrr::map_dfr(env, ~ tibble::tibble("object" = .) %>% 
                   dplyr::mutate(size = object.size(get(.x)),
                                 size = as.numeric(size),
                                 megabytes = size / 1000000))
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the solution from this [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/07/size-of-each-object-in-rs-workspace/)

```
for (thing in ls()) { message(thing); print(object.size(get(thing)), units='auto') }
```

Works fine!