# Sql query and memory

Tags: r, memory-management

I did a query with the sqlQuery function like that :

> test<- sqlQuery(ch,"
>                     SELECT USER_KEY
>                     FROM TABLE1         ")

When I want to save the result (test), the file has a weight of 200 MO, but when I take a look in the windows task manager, 7GO of memory are used.

How is it possible ?

Comment: Did you try a garbage collector after your query? It is probably due to the import himself and not the object.

Comment: After a memory-intensive task, R will hold onto the memory until the system asks for more resources. The memory usage profiled by the system is greater than the combined size of the objects in memory. [Linked here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1395270/697568) are some ways to find the memory size of your objeccts.