# (R error) Error: cons memory exhausted (limit reached?)

Tags: r, bigdata

I am working with big data and I have a 70GB JSON file.
I am using jsonlite library to load in the file into memory.

I have tried AWS EC2 x1.16large machine (976 GB RAM) to perform this load but R breaks with the error: 
`Error: cons memory exhausted (limit reached?)` 
after loading in 1,116,500 records.
Thinking that I do not have enough RAM, I tried to load in the same JSON on a bigger EC2 machine with 1.95TB of RAM.

The process still broke after loading 1,116,500 records. I am using R version 3.1.1 and I am executing it using `--vanilla` option. All other settings are default.

here is the code:

```
library(jsonlite)
data <- jsonlite::stream_in(file('one.json'))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that you're running out of memory, even on the larger EC2 instance.  Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395270/determining-memory-usage-of-objects) to see if you can figure out how much memory, e.g. 100 records, is taking.  You can extrapolate to the full size of your data set.  R operates completely in memory, so once you exceed that, expect unnice things to happen.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `handler` argument to `stream_in` that allows to handle big data. So you could write the parsed data to a file or filter the unneeded data.