# Getting memory size of all lists in the current environment

Tags: r, list

I want to get the memory usage of all lists in the current environment. `data.table` has `tables` that summarizes all tables in memory including size. Here's what I am using right now but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it:

```
sapply(ls()[grepl("list",sapply(ls(), function(z) class(get(z))))], 
       function(z) format(object.size(get(z)), units = "Mb") )
```

I've seen [Determining memory usage of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395270/determining-memory-usage-of-objects) and [Tricks to manage the available memory in an R session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) but they seem more about knowing usage of a specific item or managing memory, respectively. What I want is to get memory usage for all lists (this example) or all items that follow a certain naming convention. 
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to use `eapply` to search through all objects in the desired environment, check if each is a list and return the `object.size` if TRUE, else return NA.

```
eapply(as.environment(-1),
       FUN=function(x) if(is.list(x)) format(object.size(x), units = "Mb") else NA)
$a
[1] "7.2 Mb"

$b
[1] "72.5 Mb"

$f
[1] NA
```

The `as.environment(-1)` tells `eapply` to run over the environment that it was called from, which is the global environment here.

Also, `ls.str` might be useful here to return the `str` of list objects:

```
ls.str(mode = "list")
a : List of 2
 $ : int [1:1000000] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ : int [1:899999] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
b : List of 2
 $ : int [1:10000000] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ : int [1:8999999] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
```

**data**

```
#rm(list=ls())

f <- function() return(1)
a <- list(1:1e6, 2:9e5)
b <- list(1:1e7, 2:9e6)
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! I'll play around with it.