# What class of objects are in the environment ? (R)

Tags: class, r, object, types, environment

I wish to know what type of objects I've got in my environment.

I can show who is there like this:

```
ls()
```

But running something like

```
sapply(ls(), class)
```

Would (obviously) not tell us what type (class) of objects we are having (function, numeric, factor and so on...)

using

```
ls.str()
```

Will tell me what class my objects are, but I won't be able to (for example) ask for all the objects which are factors/data.frame/functions - and so on.

I can capture.output of ls.str(), but probably there is a smarter way - any idea what it is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
sapply(ls(), function(x){class(get(x))})
```

Comment: And just to quote official manual: `a <- get(nam)` is `assign(nam, a)`

Answer (score 6):

The `lsos()` function posted in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) answers the question too:

```
> lsos()
          Type Size Rows Columns
y   data.frame 1864   26       2
r    character  320    2      NA
txt  character  208    3      NA
x      integer   72   10      NA
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `mget()` function to get all objects at once

```
sapply(mget(ls()), class)
```