# Get locals from calling namespace in R

Tags: r

I want to be able to retrieve the local variables from R from a called function. Can I do this? (Like building a debugger.) Example:

```
show_locals <- function()
  # put something in here that shows local_1 and its value

local_1 = 123
show_locals()  # inspect local variables with custom formatting
```

Note: I will eventually require `show_locals` to be in a different library.

**Edit:** I would like to also see the value of `local_1`.

(This is similar to my questions for the same in [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589894/access-local-variables-from-a-different-binding-in-ruby) or [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618795/get-locals-from-calling-namespace-in-python).)

Comment: Can this be of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186174/what-class-of-objects-are-in-the-environment-r

Comment: @nico: it will likely involve this function, but that only provides local variables from the immediate context, not the calling context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
show_locals <- function() ls(parent.frame())
```

**Edit by Peter**: then, to get the value, use

```
print(get('local_1'), parent.frame())
```