# Append suffix to column of entries in csv file (or in SQLite database)

Tags: r, csv

I have a relatively large csv files (1.2gb... large to the 2gb RAM on one of my computers). To every entry in one column I would like to append "1C" so that I can  join/merge with another dataframe/db table.

If the file weren't so large, it would be easy to use `read.csv` to import to `data` then use `data$symbol <- paste(data$symbol, "1C", sep="")`. But now I get the `can't allocate vector of size x` warning.

Is a manual solution, like `scan()`, my only option? (I'm a bit afraid of corrupting my data) Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `scan` isn't going to help if you can already get your data into R.

Make sure `data` only has the columns you need to merge, and run `gc()` before you try your `paste` command (`gc` will help if you're near the margin of your memory limit).

If that fails, look at some of the solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session).

---

UPDATE:
And if you happen to be using a flavor of *nix, or if you have Rtools installed on windows, you could do this with `gawk`.  If your data are in `foo.csv` and you want to add the "C1" to the second column, this will create a new file, `bar.csv`, with "C1" appended to the second column.

```
compy: /home/josh
> cat foo.csv 
1,one,2,two
3,three,4,four
5,five,6,six

compy: /home/josh
> gawk -F "," '{OFS=","; $2=($2 "1C"); print}' < foo.csv > bar.csv

compy: /home/josh
> cat bar.csv 
1,one1C,2,two
3,three1C,4,four
5,five1C,6,six
```

This will likely be faster than R and will consume a negligible amount of memory.

Comment: @Joshua -- Thanks for the link! But after I get the whole csv in RAM, I don't have enough memory to `paste` back to itself (even with an element by element loop). Before I do the merge, I select just a few columns from the SQLite db that holds my data, so there's no memory issue there. I would prefer to append the "1C" before I add the csv to the database so that I can do a `join` there instead of a `merge` in R. Thanks!

Comment: @Joshua -- I'm either on either Ubuntu or OSX, so I'll give this a try!

Comment: @Joshua -- Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for! I'm still a nub at linux, so I need to dig more into these basic tools!

Comment: @richardh if you are brining this into SQLite is there a compelling reason not to do the append operation inside of SQLite?

Comment: @JD -- None other than ignorance :).  I read over the FAQ and did some fruitless googling before I posted. Is it the `||` operator?

Comment: Yep, you got it! Do the ||, then index, if needed, then join.

Answer (score 12):

This is kinda ugly, but you could read the file, line by line and put it in another file, line by line. That way you would never read the whole thing into memory. This would be not unlike Joshua's awk approach, but using R (and considerably slower). The following example was one I had cobbled together to remove dollar signs and percent signs from a csv. You can alter the logic in the middle to do the logic you want.

```
con  <- file(inputFile, open = "r")
con2 <- file(temporaryFile, open = "w")

while (length(oneLine <- readLines(con, n = 1, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {
    oneLine <- gsub("%", "", oneLine)     #strip out the percent signs
    oneLine <- gsub("\\$", "", oneLine)   #strip out the dollar signs
    cat(oneLine, file = con2, sep = "\n") #spit the line back out
  } 

close(con)
close(con2)
```

Comment: You could expand this by reading chunks of the .csv file and get at least some speed-up.

Answer (score 2):

Read only the one column and what I am assuming might be a leading unique identifier for later merge operations into memory:

```
twocol <- read.table(file="what.csv", colClasses=("numeric", "character", rep("NULL", <number-of-remaining-columns>) , sep="," )
twocol$V2 <- paste(twocol$V2, "1C", sep="")
merge(twocol, otherdf, by.x="V1" , ....)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is similar to what I was doing. My office computer is a bit old and couldn't handle the first two lines. The `merge` was fine b/c I was subsetting in SQLite before the merge, so that it was merging dataframes much smaller than the original csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Appends 1C to the second column:

`perl -F, -lane '$F[1] .= "1C"; print join ",", @F' file.csv`

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace.
- `-e` execute the perl code
- `-F` autosplit modifier, in this case splits on `,`

`@F` is the array of words in each line, indexed starting with `$F[0]`
`.=` is the "append to" operator