# Conditional input using read.table or readLines

Tags: r, input, format

I'm struggling with using `readLines()` and `read.Table()` to get a well formatted data frame in R.

I want to read files like [this](http://www.pointstreak.com/prostatstext/oberliga/teammonthly_10-2012_337457_9701.txt) which are Hockey stats. I'd like to get a nicely formatted data frame, however, specifying the concrete amount of lines to read is difficult because in other files like [this](http://www.pointstreak.com/prostatstext/oberliga/teammonthly_12-2012_337457_9701.txt) the number of players is different. Also, non-players, signed as `#.AC`, `#.HC` and so on, should not be read in.

I tried something like this

```
LINES <- 19  
stats <- read.table(file=Datei, skip=11, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                  encoding="UTF-8", nrows=LINES)
```

but as mentioned above, the value for `LINES` is different each time.

I also tried `readLines` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106764/what-is-a-good-way-to-read-line-by-line-in-r) post, but had no luck with it.

Is there a way to integrate a condition in read.table, like (pseudo code)

```
if (first character == "AC") {
    break read.table
  }
```

Sorry if this looks strange, I don't have that much experience in scripting or coding.

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!

Greetz!

Comment: I want to help but your link is down at least in my country (Senegal) can you post another link (dropbox) to get the data

Comment: @dickoa Sure, there you go:
[File 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/62ozracew6eyzl6/teammonthly_10-2011_337457_8074.txt)
[File 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xk1yna7ns679ch/teammonthly_12-2011_337457_8074.txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data show a couple of difficulties which should be handled in a sequence, which means you should not try to read the entire file with one command:

### Read plain lines and find start and stop row

Depending on the specification of the files you read in my suggestion is to first find the the first row you actually want to read in by *any* indicator. So this can be a lone number which is always the same or as in my example *two lines after the line "TEAM STATS"*. Finding the last line is then simple again by just looking for the first line containing only whitespaces after the start line:

```
lines <- readLines( Datei )
start <- which(lines == "TEAM STATS") + 2
end   <- start + min( grep( "^\\s+$", lines[ start:length(lines) ] ) ) -2
lines <- lines[start:end]
```

### Read the data to `data.frame`

In your case you meet a couple of complications:

- Your header line starts with an `#` which is on default recognized as a comment character, ignoring the line. But even if you switch this behavior off (`comment.char = ""`) it's not a valid column name.
- If we tell read.table to split the columns along whitespaces you end up with one more column in the data, than in the header since the Player column contains white spaces in the cells. So the best is at the moment to just ignore the header line and let `read.table` do this with it's default behavior (`comment.char = "#"`). Also we let the PLAYER column be split into two and will fix this later.
- You won't be able to use the first column as `row.names` since they are not unique.
- The rows have unequal length, since the POS column is not filled everywhere.

:

```
tab <- read.table( text = lines[ start:end ], fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
# fix the PLAYER column
tab$V2 <-  paste( tab$V2, tab$V3 )
tab <- tab[-3]
```

### Fix the header

Just split the start line at multiple whitespaces and reset the first entry (`#`) by a valid column name:

```
colns <- strsplit( lines[start], "\\s+" )[[1]]
colns[1] <- "code"
colnames(tab) <- colns
```

### Fix cases were "POS" was empty

This is done by finding the rows which last cell contains `NA`s and shift them by one cell to the right:

```
colsToFix <- which( is.na(tab[, "SHO%"]) )
tab[ colsToFix, 4:ncol(tab) ] <- tab[ colsToFix, 3:(ncol(tab)-1) ]
tab[ colsToFix, 3  ] <- NA

> str(tab)
'data.frame':   25 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ code  : chr  "93" "91" "61" "88" ...
 $ PLAYER: chr  "Eichelkraut, Flori" "Müller, Lars" "Alt, Sebastian" "Gross, Arthur" ...
 $ POS   : chr  "F" "F" "D" "F" ...
 $ GP    : chr  "8" "6" "7" "8" ...
 $ G     : int  10 1 4 3 4 2 0 2 1 0 ...
 $ A     : int  5 11 5 5 3 4 6 3 3 4 ...
 $ PTS   : int  15 12 9 8 7 6 6 5 4 4 ...
 $ PIM   : int  12 10 12 6 2 36 37 29 6 0 ...
 $ PPG   : int  3 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ PPA   : int  1 5 2 2 1 2 4 2 1 1 ...
 $ SHG   : int  0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SHA   : int  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ GWG   : int  2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FG    : int  1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ OTG   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ UAG   : int  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ENG   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SHOG  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SHOA  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SHO%  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed guide on how to solve my problem. I'll be trying out your suggestions!

Comment: Thanks again, it works. What really helped was the first part, treat the whole file as one string and then look for matching patterns. :D