# How to read a table line by line - using R?

Tags: r

I have a pretty big (20GB) CSV file, and I need to modify some of its columns.
What is the MOST OPTIMIZED way of importing the data table line by line (or probably few thousands of line per read) ? 
I have tried the solution given below
[What is a good way to read line-by-line in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106764/what-is-a-good-way-to-read-line-by-line-in-r)

But it seems to be very slow. Is there any library which can read line by line, in the table structure itself -- also which has some kind of Buffer logic to make the read faster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fast `fread()` from `data.table`.
By `skip=`, you're setting the beginning of the read segment and by `nrow=`, the number of rows to read.