# R formule with readLines

Tags: r, readlines

I'm new in R and am trying to make a formula with the function readLines, but all the time R returned the same errors and do not know how to fix it. Any suggestions?

**my formula**

```
sam.cover<-function(){
     readLines()->CH
     gsub("00","0,0",CH)->CH
     gsub("01","0,1",CH)->CH
     gsub("10","1,0",CH)->CH
     gsub("11","1,1",CH)->CH
     gsub(" 1;","",CH)->CH
     gsub("00","0,0",CH)->CH
     gsub("01","0,1",CH)->CH
     gsub("01","1,0",CH)->CH
     gsub("11","1,1",CH)->CH
     write.table(CH,"temporaryfile.txt",quo=F,sep="",row=F,col=F)
     as.matrix(read.table("temporaryfile.txt",sep=","))->CH
     matrix(CH,nr=dim(CH)[ 1])->CH
     apply(CH,1,sum)->SUM
     CF<-999
     t<-dim(CH)[ 2]
     for(i in 1:t){
         CF<-c(CF,sum(SUM==i))
     }
     cat("Capture frequencies : ","\n")
     print(rbind(1:i,CF[ -1])->CF)
     f1<-CF[ 2,1]
     f2<-CF[ 2,2]
     f3<-CF[ 2,3]
     cat("Sample coverage estimates : ","\n")
     cat("C1-hat =",1-f1/sum(apply(CF,2,prod)),"\n")
     cat("C2-hat =",1-(f1-2*f2/(t-1))/sum(apply(CF,2,prod)),"\n")
     cat("C3-hat =",1-(f1-2*f2/(t-1)+6*f3/(t-1)/(t-2))/sum(apply(CF,2,prod)),"\n")
 }
```

**my Data**

```
ide    c1   c2  c3  c4  c5
N19 1   1   1   0   1
N29 0   0   1   1   0
N39 0   0   1   0   1
N49 0   0   0   1   1
N59 0   0   1   0   0
```

**my error:**

```
Error in readLines(histoire.inp) : 'con' is not a connection
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've provided an answer for `readLines`, but I will ask if you're aware of `read.table` since you said you're new to R.

Answer (score 1):

The `readLines` argument operates on a `connection`, so if you want to read a file line by line, you need to do a little bit more work than just giving it the path.

First, you need to open a `connection` to your file:

```
conn <- file("histoire.inp", "rt")  # second argument indicates we're reading a text file.
```

Then, if you want to read the file in line by line, I find the following code block useful ([Original idea here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4082480/2341679)):

```
while (length(oneLine <- readLines(conn, n = 1, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {
   # Do something to your line of text, stored in `oneLine`
}
close(conn)
```

You can change `n` to something bigger if you want to read in the file in blocks.