# Easy way to list my data but not my functions in R? (Hide functions from ls()?)

Tags: r

In a long-term project that uses R, I have a set of about 50 functions that I've defined which I use all the time, and another 10 or 15 that I use once in a while.  Most of these are not functions I use directly; they're helper functions I've used to define the ones I use directly.  When I load data objects from R data files, I don't always remember what I named the objects, so I execute `ls()` to see what I loaded.  If I've loaded my source doe files, though, I have to visually sift through the output to fine the data objects, which is obviously inconvenient.

So I wrapped the functions into an R package.  If I just load the package, then everything is fine.  I can use the functions, but `ls()` only shows me the data objects.

However, I keep adding new functions.  And I find that remaking the package is not entirely trivial, so I end up loading my functions from the source files anyway much of the time--until I get around to remaking the package.

I can of course automate the package construction process more than I have, or split my new functions out in separate source files.  I could also split the functions into different packages--maybe that would help.  I think I could make the helper functions available only via a closure over the ones I call directly--I haven't tried that--but then I can't use the helpers directly if I want to do so, and it seems like overkill if there's a simpler way.  And that's what I'm  wondering: whether there's an easy trick that I've missed--a way to make functions available for use, but make it easy to show me what data objects I have without listing the functions.  If not, OK, but I thought it would be worth asking.  Thanks.

These questions:
[hiding personal functions in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828094/hiding-personal-functions-in-r) and
[remove all variables except functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305754/remove-all-variables-except-functions)
provide very useful answers.  What is the absolutely easiest way to accomplish what's described above?

Comment: RStudio displays the workspace organized in data, values, and functions. If you haven't already done so, you should give it a try. There are lots of other benefits in using an IDE.

Comment: I'm guessing that since you don't think 'remaking' the package is trivial that you aren't using the devtools package.  It makes it really easy to make modifications to a package, test them out, and reinstall the package.

Comment: Even without devtools, "remaking" a package isn't difficult.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich No - but I find `document(); install()` trivial whereas the alternative, while not difficult, isn't necessarily trivial.  Unless you make a script to do it - which isn't too bad - but still not as easy as the process with devtools IMO.

Comment: Thanks for all of the helpful suggestions (and duplicate answer references).  Did think it would have been answered, but was unsuccessful searching for it.  (David Heffernan in [hiding personal functions in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828094/hiding-personal-functions-in-r) expressed my situation.)  Will try devtools and the other tricks suggested.

Comment: Also, @Roland, re RStudio--good idea.  I've used it some and will explore it further.  Usually use R.app.  I guess I like the visual simplicity of the interface in R.app, and I keep getting caught off guard in RStudio when ^P doesn't recall the last command; that's just second nature to me when working at a prompt.  You've pointed out a benefit that might outweigh the costs.

Comment: Spacedman's answer provides new information that's not explicit in the answers to previous questions.  (@Matthew Plourde's answer is given in [remove all variables except functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305754/remove-all-variables-except-functions), though his version is very slightly clearer given the question I asked.)  As a result, I suggest that this not be marked as a duplicate question.  I've edited my question to include links to the previous questions, but have suggested there might be an easier method--which there is: Spacedman's.  Not sure this is best way to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the functions in a package-structured folder (ie in a subfolder called R) and use package:devtools. The only thing you need do is `load_all("myfuncs")` when you edit your R code. Everything is reloaded into R, doesn't mess up your `ls()` listings, and is easy to package and document if you need to take this further. But its not compulsory. Just `load_all` after editing.

Comment: This is great!  Perfect. Thank you @Spacedman for sending me immediately to the shortest of shortcuts.

Comment: I also added a suggested edit: A DESCRIPTION file is needed to make this work.

Answer (score 10):

`lsf.str` returns a vector of the functions in your namespace, so you could use this to remove those names from the output of `ls`.

```
setdiff(ls(), lsf.str())
```