# Why has data.table defined := rather than overloading <-?

Tags: r, data.table, colon-equals

data.table has introduced the := operator. Why not overload <-?

Comment: Let me guess: In homage to Pascal!!!

Comment: I guess! We couldn't choose any operator, it was just that (fortunately) R allows := to be defined. Otherwise we could have fun and define +=, -=, ~= etc :)

Comment: Could someone please explain what "overloading <-" means?

Comment: @Michael "Overloading" roughly speaking meant replacing `<-` with another version of `<-` that works differently. Making `<-` work differently, somehow. Instead, we used a new operator, `:=`, for clarity amongst other reasons. Almost everything in R is a function, even `<-` and `[` etc.

Comment: @Michael But probably 'overloading' was technically incorrect, as Owen pointed out in comments. I meant it in a loose sense.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think there is any technical reason this should be necessary, for the following reason: `:=` is only used inside `[...]` so it is always quoted. `[...]` goes through the expression tree to see if `:=` is in it.

That means it's not really acting as an operator and it's not really overloaded; so they could have picked pretty much any operator they wanted. I guess maybe it looked better? Or less confusing because it's clearly not `<-`?

(Note that if `:=` were used *outside* of `[...]` it could not be `<-`, because you can't actually overload `<-`. `<-` Doesn't evaluate its lefthand argument so it doesn't know what the type is).

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. We tried <- first actually but that didn't fly because user code already used <- in j e.g. incrementing a group counter. Then we tried <<- but people already use that in j too, to assign to .GlobalEnv. So then we hit upon :=.

Answer (score 32):

There are two places that `<-` could be 'overloaded' :

```
x[i, j] <- value           # 1
x[i, {colname <- value}]   # 2
```

The first one copies the whole of `x` to `*tmp*`, changes that working copy, and assigns back to `x`. That's an R thing (src/main/eval.c and subassign.c) discussed recently on r-devel [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/speeding-up-perception-tp3640920p3646694.html). It sounded like it might be possible to change R to allow packages, or R itself, to avoid that copy to `*tmp*`, but isn't currently possible, IIUC.

The second one is what Owen's answer refers to, I think. If you accept that it's ok to do assignment by reference within `j` like that, then which operator?  As per the comment to Owen's answer, `<-` and `<<-` are already used by users in `j`, so we hit upon `:=`.

Even if `[<-` didn't copy the whole of `x`, we still like `:=` in `j` so we can do things like this :

```
DT[,{newcol1:=sum(a)
     newcol2:=a/newcol1}, by=group]
```

Where the new columns are added by reference to the table, and the RHS of each `:=` is evaluated within each group. (When := within group is implemented.)

---

**Update Oct 2012**

As of 1.8.2 (on CRAN in Jul 2012), `:=` *by group* was implemented for adding or updating single columns; i.e., single LHS of `:=`. And now in v1.8.3 (on R-Forge at the time of writing), multiple columns can be added by group; e.g.,

```
DT[, c("newcol1","newcol2") := .(sum(a),sum(b)), by=group]
```

or, perhaps more elegantly :

```
DT[,`:=`(newcol1=sum(a),
         newcol2=sum(b)), by=group]
```

But the *iterative* multiple RHS, envisaged for a while, where the 2nd expression could use the result from the first, isn't implemented yet ([FR#1492](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1492&group_id=240&atid=978)). So this will still give an error `"newcol1 not found"` and need to be done in two steps :

```
DT[,`:=`(newcol1=sum(a),
         newcol2=a/newcol1), by=group]
```

Comment: Just a minor thing, `x[i, j] <- value` isn't actually overloading `<-`, rather `<-` does what it always does by delegating to `[<-` (based on the expression, not the value type).

Comment: @Owen Ah yes, good point. Have edited and added quotes around 'overloaded'.