# Extend data.table dynamically

Tags: r, data.table

I know that when I'm building up a `data.table` row-by-row, it's best to pre-allocate space:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=rep(0,1000), y=rep(0,1000))
for(i in 1L:1000L) {
    set(dt, i, 1L, runif(1))
    set(dt, i, 2L, rnorm(1))
}
```

(In fact, if I don't pre-allocate, I get a segmentation fault with that code.)

If I don't know the number of rows in advance, then I need to grow dynamically, probably using exponential allocation or something.  Will I need to manage that process myself, or is there any existing support in `data.table` for dynamic growth?

Also, when I'm done appending rows, I'll probably have some allocated space left over, is there a `truncate()` method or similar?  Or should I just do `dt <- dt[1:n,]`?

Comment: Regarding the segfault, I was going to post it as a bug report, but I can't always seem to duplicate it.  It might have something to do with RStudio & the way it refreshes the session when building packages.

Comment: How about making a temp data.table and then `rbindlist` the "master" with the temp?

Comment: I think that's basically the same as simply `rbind`-ing a new extension on the bottom each time I need to grow, right?

Comment: I think the suggestion is not to `rbind` to a `data.table`, but put the results in a list and then `rbindlist` everything together. That will avoid copying on every step.

Comment: There are plans to have  "insert rows by reference" functionality - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-r-data-table