# Match rows on several variables efficiently - exclusion of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am working on a financial problem of deleting messages from a financial center. I am using data.table and I am very satisfied with its performance and easy handling.

Though, I ask myself always how to improve and use the whole power of data.table.

Here is an example of my task:

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(SYM = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 12)), PRC = format(rlnorm(22, 2), digits = 2), VOL = rpois(22, 312), ID = c(seq(1000, 1009), seq(1004, 1015)), FLAG = c(rep("", 8), "R", "A", rep("", 4), "R", rep("", 7)))
DT$PRC[9] <- DT$PRC[6]
DT$PRC[7] <- DT$PRC[6] 
DT$VOL[9] <- DT$VOL[6]
DT$VOL[7] <- DT$VOL[6]
DT$PRC[15] <- DT$PRC[13]
DT$VOL[15] <- DT$VOL[13]
## See the original dataset
DT
## Set the key
setkey(DT, "SYM", "PRC", "VOL", "FLAG")
## Get all rows, that match a row with FLAG == "R" on the given variables in the list
DT[DT[FLAG == "R"][,list(SYM, PRC, VOL)]]
## Remove these rows from the dataset
DT <- DT[!DT[FLAG == "R"][,list(SYM, PRC, VOL)]]
## See the modified data.table
DT
```

My questions are now:

1. Is this an efficient way to perform my task or does there exist something more 'data.table' style? Is the key set efficiently?
2. How can I perform my task if I do not only have three variables to match on (here: SYM, PRC, VOL) but a lot more, does there exist something like exclusion (I do know I can use it data.frame style but I want to know if there is a more elegant way for a data.table)?
3. What is with the copying in the last command? Following the thread on [remove row by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-r-data-table), I think copying is the only way to do it. What if I have several tasks, can I compound them in a way and avoid copying for each task?

Comment: +1 Is that data random? I see an `rlnorm` (though I'm not sure what that is). Could you use `set.seed(1)` (or some other seed) at the top so we're all on the same page? You're doing pretty much what I would do, though I'd keep two versions of the table DT1 <- DT[!...], since I'm not used to hitting memory constraints.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for this comment! You are true! And my data is not random at all :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only setting the key to perform this operation, @eddi's answer is the best and easiest to read.

```
setkey(DT, SYM, PRC, VOL)
# ^ as in @eddi's answer, since you are not using the rest of the key
microbenchmark(
    notjoin=DT[!DT[FLAG == "R"][,list(SYM, PRC, VOL)]],
    logi_not=DT[!DT[,rep(any(FLAG=='R'),.N),by='SYM,PRC,VOL']$V1],
    idx_not=DT[!DT[,if(any(FLAG=='R')){.I}else{NULL},by='SYM,PRC,VOL']$V1],
    SD=DT[,if(!any(FLAG=='R')){.SD}else{NULL},by='SYM,PRC,VOL'],
    eddi=DT[!DT[FLAG == "R"]],
    times=1000L
)
```

results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
  notjoin 4.983404 5.577309 5.715527 5.903417 66.468771  1000
 logi_not 4.393278 4.960187 5.097595 5.273607 66.429358  1000
  idx_not 4.523397 5.139439 5.287645 5.453129 15.068991  1000
       SD 3.670874 4.180012 4.308781 4.463737  9.429053  1000
     eddi 2.767599 3.047273 3.137979 3.255680 11.970966  1000
```

On the other hand, several of options above do not require that your operation involve grouping by the key. Suppose you either...

- are doing this once using groups other than the key (which you don't want to change) or
- want to perform several operations like this using different groupings before doing the copy operation to drop rows, `newDT <- DT[...]` (as mentioned in the OP's point 3).

.

```
setkey(DT,NULL)
shuffDT <- DT[sample(1:nrow(DT))] # not realistic, of course
# same benchmark with shuffDT, but without methods that require a key
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  logi_not 4.466166 5.120273 5.298174 5.562732 64.30966  1000
#   idx_not 4.623821 5.319501 5.517378 5.799484 15.57165  1000
#        SD 4.053672 4.448080 4.612213 4.849505 66.76140  1000
```

In these cases, the OP's and eddi's methods are not available (since joining requires a key). For a one-off operation, using `.SD` seems faster. For subsetting by multiple criteria, you'll want to keep track of the rows you want to keep/drop before making the copy `newDT <- DT[!union(badrows1,badrows2,...)]`.

```
DT[,rn:=1:.N] # same as .I
badflagrows <- DT[,if(any(FLAG=='R')){rn}else{NULL},by='SYM,PRC,VOL']$V1
# fill in next_cond, next_grp
badnextrows <- DT[!badflagrows][,
    if(any(next_cond)){rn}else{NULL},by='next_grp']$V1
```

Perhaps something similar can be done with the logical subsetting ("logi_not" in the benchmarks), which is a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused why you're setting the key to `FLAG`, isn't what you want simply

```
setkey(DT, SYM, PRC, VOL)

DT[!DT[FLAG == "R"]]
```

Comment: @eddi Indeed, it is. Good to know, I thought, that the table must also have "FLAG" in its key to be able to search for "R" in this variable. Thank you very much for your help!