# How to remove a single value in datatable?

Tags: r, null, data.table

Let's say that I want to delete the data in ith row and jth col in a data table by setting it to NULL:

```
dt[i, j := NULL,with=F]

set(dt1,i,j,value=NULL)
```

Both of the above options gave me the error: When deleting columns, i should not be provided

However if I don't provide i , the entire column in the data table gets deleted, which is not what I want.

So how do I delete a single value in a datatable?

Comment: A single value can be `NA`, not `NULL`. Missing values in R are indicated with `NA` and they play the same role as NULL in some DBMS, like MySQL.

Comment: Deletion by reference is not yet supported. Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-r-data-table

Comment: I don't know how your data.table looks, but this works: `xy <- data.table(B = 1:10, C = 11:20); xy[4, 2] <- NA_integer_`. Will this get you what you want?

Comment: thank you everyone, I see that I can only set it to NA instead of NULL, this answers my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sense of a data.table you can't *delete* item in a cell. You can change its value to *missing* which (most likely) will achieve what you're looking for using something like

```
dt[i, j := NA]
```

This will set value of column `j` in row `i` to NA, or *unset* it, in other terms. Later when you want to work with these values or exclude them you could use `is.na(..)` similarly how you would think of `is.null(..)`

Regarding the error you're getting, `j := NULL` is used in `data.table` to delete an entire column, and indeed when you try to delete a part of it (by specifying `i`) it produced an error.
If you're looking to remove an entire *row* from data table, you could use something like

```
dt <- dt[-i] # exclude row i from the data.table
```