# how to update a data.table by its subset?

Tags: r, data.table, subset, large-data

Suppose we have a huge data.frame `data` (60000x8000) which has been converted as data.table by `setDT(data)`. This will create a reference of `data` rather than make a copy of it, which is great. Then I want to obtain a subset, for example, the first 40000 rows, of `data`.

```
id <- rep(FALSE, nrow(data))
id[1:40000] <- TRUE
data <- subset(data, id)
```

However, the code above doesn't perform well, since it will make a copy of `data`, and I need to manually call `gc()` to release the memory. In my example, additional 1.6 GB was consumed by `subset`, which can be completely released by `gc()`. I have read some documents about the use of `data.table` and maybe I have missed something important. The examples I have found focus on extracting the subset of a `data.table` and then assign it to a new variable, instead of to update the original one. For example:

```
new.data <- subset(data, id)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `data[1:40000]` is enough to get the first 40000 rows.

Comment: @nicola Yes, but `data <- data[1:40000, ]` still makes a copy. The original `data` takes about 2 GB, and overall 3.6 GB are used after `data <- data[1:40000, ]` is run. Is there a more memory efficient way to update `data` as its subset?

Comment: If I understand you, you want to remove rows by reference. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-r-data-table and in particular @vc273 answer that offers a workaround for this problem.

Comment: @nicola vc273 gave a great solution on it! Thank you.