# set data.table by reference inside a function

Tags: r, data.table

Here is a very light example of what I want to do.

```
test <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))

f1 <- function(){
  test2 <- data.table(a=c(4,5,6),b=c(1,2,3))
  test <- copy(test2)
}

f1()

> test
   a b
1: 1 4
2: 2 5
3: 3 6
```

I would like to copy `test2` into `test` by reference directly into the function `f1()` so that the output would be

```
> test
   a b
1: 4 1
2: 5 2
3: 6 3
```

I know that `<-` is making a copy, I would like to do the same, copying a data.table, but by reference. Is there a way to make that possible?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying by reference is an oxymoron in this context (where a "copy" has a distinct memory address).

Currently, *replacing* the contents of a data.table by reference cannot be done for arbitrary data.tables, since [there is no way of modifying the number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791729/1191259) (which may be different in `test` and `test2`) by reference.

In the special case of replacing a data.table with another having the same number of rows...

```
(test <- data.table(x=1:3)); address(test)
#    x
# 1: 1
# 2: 2
# 3: 3
# [1] "0000000016286280"

f1 <- function(){
  test2 <- data.table(y=LETTERS[1:3])

  test[, names(test2) := test2]
  test[, setdiff(names(test),names(test2)) := NULL]
}

f1()
test; address(test)
#    y
# 1: A
# 2: B
# 3: C
# [1] "0000000016286280"
```

There is probably a slicker way of achieving this goal, but I'm not sure it's a worthwhile thing to do to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Frank, I appreciate it. In my concrete example, both `test` and `test2` have the same number of rows, so I will use your suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Simply return out of `f1`

```
f1 <- function(){
    test2 <- data.frame(a=c(4,5,6),b=c(1,2,3))
    return(test2)
}
```

via

```
test <- f1()
```

yielding

```
> test
  a b
1 4 1
2 5 2
3 6 3
```