# Apply which.min to data.table under a condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` and need to know the index of the row containing a minimal value under a given condition. Simple example:

```
dt <- data.table(i=11:13, val=21:23)

#     i  val
# 1: 11   21
# 2: 12   22
# 3: 13   23
```

Now, suppose I'd like to know in which row `val` is minimal under the condition `i>=12`, which is *2* in this case.

### What didn't work:

```
dt[i>=12, which.min(val)]
# [1] 1
```

returns *1*, because within `dt[i>=12]` it is the first row.

Also

```
dt[i>=12, .I[which.min(val)]]
# [1] 1
```

returned *1*, because `.I` is only supposed to be used with grouping.

### What did work:

To apply `.I` correctly, I added a grouping column:

```
dt[i>=12, g:=TRUE]
dt[i>=12, .I[which.min(val)], by=g][, V1]
# [1] 2
```

Note, that `g` is `NA` for `i<12`, thus `which.min` excludes that group from the result.

*But*, this requires extra computational power to add the column and perform the grouping. My productive `data.table` has several millions of rows and I have to find the minimum very often, so I'd like to avoid any extra computations.

**Do you have any idea, how to efficiently solve this?**

Comment: Why not just `dt[, idx := .I][i >= 12, idx[which.min(val)]]` where you create an index variable first? The overhead will be tiny surely.

Comment: @thelatemail: Interesting. I tried something with an index column, but it was more cumbersome so I left it out. However, it also requires adding another column but at least avoids grouping.

Comment: You might want to also consider a dense rank if you are removing minimum values, then the next minimum, the the next... etc `frank(c(2,5,1,3,1),ties.method="dense")` for instance.

Comment: @thelatemail: Nice tip, didn't know about ``frank`` (or ``rank``), yet. However, I have to compute new values on each round, so the ranks will be different each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that `which.min` will ignore NA values to "mask" the values you don't want to consider:

```
dt[,which.min(ifelse(i>=12, val, NA))]
```

As a simple example of this behavior, `which.min(c(NA, 2, 1))` returns 3, because the 3rd element is the min among all the non-NA values.

Comment: Thanks, this looks quite efficient to me. I assume it has to go through the rows only two times resulting in a ``O(2*n)`` complexity.

Comment: I think that's right. Once to build the masked value vector and again to find the min.

Answer (score 6):

> *But*, this requires extra computational power to add the column and perform the grouping.

So, keep the data sorted by it if it's so important:

```
setorder(dt, val)
dt[.(i_min = 12), on=.(i >= i_min), mult="first", which = TRUE]
# 2
```

This can also be extended to check more threshold `i` values. Just give a vector in `i_min =`:

```
dt[.(i_min = 9:14), on=.(i >= i_min), mult="first", which = TRUE]
# [1]  1  1  1  2  3 NA
```

*How it works*

`x[i, on=, ...]` is the syntax for a join.

- `i` can be another table or equivalently a list of equal-length vectors.
- `.()` is a shorthand for `list()`.
- `on=` can have inequalities for a "non-equi join".
- `mult=` can determine what happens when a row of `i` has more than one match in `x`.
- `which=TRUE` will return row numbers of `x` instead of the full joined table.

Comment: Wow, this is very impressive. It took me quite a while to understand it in detail. It's unbelievable, what a powerful tool ``data.table`` joins are. Thanks for this insight. However, my ``data.table`` is huge and I've to search for the minimum very often after removing the previous minimum from the ``data.table``. So, I'm afraid sorting will cost too much as even the ``log n`` in ``O(n * log n)`` becomes big.

Comment: @bjhend If you mean that you remove rows, that can be very costly and is probably best avoided (since it can't be done without copying the whole table yet https://stackoverflow.com/q/10790204/ ). You could maybe "remove" by setting `i` to missing/NA. Even if you for some reason need to make a new table by dropping rows, if it was sorted before removal, it will still be sorted afterwards (since that's how sorting works), right?

Comment: I already suspected that removing is the biggest performance killer in my code (I know ``data.table``s are stored column-wise). So, I will definitely try your suggestion. Unfortunately, I cannot avoid reordering, because on every round I have to compute new values of which I've to find the minimum.

Comment: Ok. Well, as you become more familiar with the syntax, you'll probably come up with other ways to improve efficiency that suit your use case.