# One to Many Join in data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

I am using data.table to do a one-to-many merge. Instead of matching with all the rows, the output is showing only the last matched row for each unique value of the key.

```
a <- data.table(x = 1:2L, y = letters[1:4])
b <- data.table(x = c(1L,3L))

setkey(a,x)
setkey(b,x)
```

I want to do a many to one (b to a) join based on column x.

```
c <- a[b,on=.(x)]
c
#    x  y
# 1: 1  a
# 2: 1  c
# 3: 3 NA
```

However, this approach creates a new data.table called c, instead of making a new data.table, I use the following code to add the column y with b.

```
b[a,y:=i.y]
```

Now `b` looks like,

```
b
#    x  y
# 1: 1  c
# 2: 3 NA
```

The desired output is the one in the first method (`c`). Is there a way of using `:=` and output all the rows instead of the last matched row alone?

PS: The reason I want to use method 2 using `:=` is because my data is huge and I do not want to make copies. The example I showed reflects what happens in my data.

Comment: There is no way achieving this using `:=` I'm aware of. You are basically want to add new rows to `b` by reference. This has been asked before already, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-data-table

Comment: Yeah, I think a new table is the right output for this operation. All data.table modifications by reference preserve #rows. You could collapse the values from `a`, eg `b[, y := a[b, toString(x.y), by=.EACHI]$V1]`, though I guess that is unlikely to be useful unless the values are only for browsing / not used in later analysis.