# Why I need to assign a data.table to a new object to filter rows?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm just starting to learn data.table in r and

```
library(data.table)
data(iris)
iris[Species == 'setosa']
```

The code above doesn't filter the rows where the species are setosa in the dataset, it just print the rows where the condition is satisfied.

```
iris <- iris[Species == 'setosa']
```

The above code works, but I'm wondering what kind of situation I need to assign a new object for the operation to be effective and not just print the results. Also, is there any risk in assigning on the same object?

Comment: This question has been addressed in detail here: [How to delete a row by reference in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-data-table) To summarize, rows cannot be deleted in place, and the method you are using _(assigning to the same object)_ is the correct and idiomatic way to accomplish this task. _(Unless of course, [this feature request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/635) is ever implemented)_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fundamentally, columns are much easier to modify by-reference in R since columns  are list elements, and list elements are not stored contiguously in memory.

Removing a column by reference just means unallocating its allotted memory and removing the associated pointers

By contrast, removing some rows is a lot harder and can't *really* be done by-reference -- some copying is inevitable. Consider this simplified representation of a table with two columns, `A` and `B`:

```
    1  2  3  4  5
A: [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
B: [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

`A` is stored in contiguous memory as an array with size `5*sizeof(A)`. E.g. if `A` is an `integer`, it's given 4 bytes per cell. `numeric` is 8 bytes per cell.

Deleting `B` is easy from a memory point of view: just tell R/your system you don't need that memory anymore:

```
    1  2  3  4  5
A: [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
B: [x][x][x][x][x]
```

`A`'s memory allocation is unaffected.

By contrast, consider removing some rows from the table (i.e., both `A` and `B`):

```
    1  2  3  4  5
A: [ ][x][x][ ][ ]
B: [ ][x][x][ ][ ]
```

If we simply release the memory for these 4 cells, our table will be broken -- its constituent memory has been split with the `2*sizeof(A)`-size gaps between its 1st and 4th rows.

The best we can do is to try and minimize copying by shifting rows 4 & 5, and leaving row 1 alone:

```
    1  2  3<-4<-5
A: [ ][x][x][ ][ ]
B: [ ][x][x][ ][ ]

    1  4  5
A: [ ][ ][ ]
B: [ ][ ][ ]
```

In the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791729/3576984), Matt alludes to a very specific case in which the by-reference approach can work -- when the rows to add/drop come at the end. Hopefully the illustration makes it clear why this is easier to do.

This technical difficulty is the reason why the [linked feature request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/635) is so hard to fill. Copying many columns' data as illustrated is easier said than done & requires a lot of finesse to get it working & communicated back to R from C properly.