# Delete NA rows in data.table by not using the assignment

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table from which I want to remove those rows which have NA value in any column.

```
a <- data.table(s = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA, 3, 2), d = c(32, 23, 2, 121, NA, 3, NA))
```

So to remove NA values from this data.table, I will have to assign it back to `a`:-

```
a <- na.omit(a)
```

In this way it will create a new object `a` in a new memory address.

I want to know if there is a way in which I can use data.table syntax (`[i, j, by]`) which can remove the NA values, take care of the assignment and not create a new memory address for `a`.

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible. You are changing the size of the vectors in the data.table. I don't think a copy can be avoided.

Comment: Related: [How to delete a row by reference in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-data-table); "data.table can't delete rows by reference yet"

Comment: Which packages is data.table from?

Comment: Perhaps you can avoid these rows earlier, depending on how you are reading in the data. @JAQuent `data.table()` is, .... (surprise), from the `data.table` package.

Comment: I'm taking that comment/question as a reminder to myself. Several times, I've asked about functions/packages implied by a question, only to realize that the tags indicated the package(s). It's easy (for me, at least) to go through a question and not even *register* the tags (heck, I've even skipped a paragraph a few times).