# Subsetting by reference in `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table

I am wondering if it is possible to subset a data.table by reference.

A solution that involves updating by assignment is:

```
iris <- as.data.table(iris)

iris <- iris[Species == "virginica"]
```

The downside of this approach is it copies the filtered data.table. If possible, I would like to filter by reference, possibly using the `:=` operator and the `.SD` shortcut.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If all you want is to replace `iris` with a subset of itself, it will necessarily create a new object in memory.

Comment: Is that because subseting behaves differently than adding or removing columns? I'm trying to understand if there is a way to subset by reference just like there is a way to add or remove columns by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [How to delete a row by reference in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-data-table)

You can modify a subset of a `data.table` by reference, though:

```
iris <- as.data.table(iris)
address(iris)
#> [1] "000001dc87099330"
```

An object that is a row subset of `iris` requires a new object in memory.

```
iris2 <- iris[Species == "virginica"]
address(iris2)
#> [1] "000001dc876cdc30"
```

Modifying a subset of a column or adding/deleting a column can be done by reference.

```
iris[Species == "virginica", Species := "virg"]
address(iris)
#> [1] "000001dc87099330"
iris[,Species := NULL]
address(iris)
#> [1] "000001dc87099330"
iris[,Species := "virginica"]
address(iris)
#> [1] "000001dc87099330"
```