# Does appending to a list in R result in copying?

Tags: r, list, append

Suppose I have create a list in R and append to it as follows:

```
x = list(10)
x[[2]] = 20
```

Is this equivalent to

```
x = list(10)
x = list(10, 20)
```

? I'm not so experienced with the particular details of how R handles lists in memory, but my limited understanding is that it tends to be copy-happy; what would be ideal for me would be that the first option doesn't involve essentially creating another list in memory, but just results in setting aside a new place in memory for the appended value. Essentially, if I have a big list, I don't want R to make another copy of it if I just want to append something to it.

If the behaviour I want is not what is given here, is there any other way I can get the desired effect?

Comment: maybe `?tracemem` would be of use?

Comment: And `.Internal(inspect(x))` before and after.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm fairly confident the answer is "no". I used the following code to double check:

```
Rprof(tmp <- tempfile(), memory.profiling = TRUE)

x <- list()
for (i in 1:100) x[[i]] <- runif(10000)

Rprof()
summaryRprof(tmp, memory = "stats")
unlink(tmp)
```

The output:

```
# index: runif
#      vsize.small  max.vsize.small      vsize.large  max.vsize.large 
#            76411           381781           424523          1504387 
#            nodes        max.nodes     duplications tot.duplications 
#          2725878         13583136                0                0 
#          samples 
#                5
```

The relevant part being `duplications = 0`.

Comment: I don't think your reasoning is  necessarily correct: duplications have a special meaning in R, and technically, while extending the the length of a vector creates a copy, it is not a duplication. See this thread on R-help: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Understanding-tracemem-td4636321.html

Answer (score 12):

Matthew Dowle's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033106/why-has-data-table-defined-rather-than-overloading) and the rationale behind much memory efficiency is to stop the numerous behind the scenes copying by `<-`, `[<-`, `[[<-` and other base `R` operations (`names` etc)

`[[<-` will copy the whole of `x`. See the example below

```
x <- list(20)
 tracemem(x)
#[1] "<0x2b0e2790>"
 x[[2]] <- 20
# tracemem[0x2b0e2790 -> 0x2adb7798]:
```

Your second case

```
x <- list(10,20)
```

is not really appending the original `x` but replacing `x` with an object that happens to be the original `x` with an appended value.

Comment: (+1), The second case isn't appending, or an example of something I was proposing, but rather an example of something I don't want R to be doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Ahh, I misread your question, it first read to me as you were asking whether `x <- list(10,20)`, was the equivalent (in terms of memory) to `x <- list(10); x[[2]] <- 20`. On rereading I see that it was more nuanced than that.

Comment: Yes but in that linked answer `x` was a `data.frame`. In this question `x` is a `list`. Copying behaviour of `list` can be different. Note that there is no `[<-.list` method but there is a `[<-.data.frame`. Use `.Internal(inspect(x))` to check.

Answer (score 9):

To help me figure out whether or not modifying a list makes a deep copy or a shallow copy, I set up a small experiment.  If modifying a list makes a deep copy, then it should be slower when you're modifying a list that contains a large object compared to a list that contains a small object:

```
z1 <- list(runif(1e7))
z2 <- list(1:10)

system.time({
  for(i in 1:1e4) z1[1 + i] <- 1L
})
#  user  system elapsed
# 0.283   0.034   0.317
system.time({
  for(i in 1:1e4) z2[1 + i] <- 1L
})
#  user  system elapsed
# 0.284   0.034   0.319
```

The timings on my computer were basically identical, suggesting that copying a list makes a shallow copy, copying pointers to existing data structures.

Comment: `.Internal(inspect(x))` is a more concrete way to tell. Looking to see if the hex address of the long vector has changed.

Answer (score 5):

Accepted flodel's answer, but Chase's tip was good so I confirmed that I have the desired behavior using his suggestion of using `tracemem()`. Here is the first example, where we just append to the list:

```
x = list(10)
tracemem(x[[1]])
# [1] "<0x2d03fa8>" #(likely different on each machine)
x[[2]] = 20
tracemem(x[[1]])
# [1] "<0x2d03fa8>"
```

And here is the result from the second example, where we create two lists:

```
x = list(10)
tracemem(x[[1]])
# [1] "<0x2d03c78>"
x = list(10, 20)
tracemem(x[[1]])
# [1] "<0x2d07ff8>"
```

So the first method appears to give the desired behaviour.