# Predetermination of max memory allocation for a growing list file in loops (R)

Tags: r, loops, memory-management, size, out-of-memory

When you have a `x<-list()` file in a loop, as function progress, its size increases and therefore memory allocation also increases. After a while you may encounter with memory `error`. **How is it possible** to guess max needed memory and also dedicate it from the beginning?

Can making a **pre-defined size** make sense? Or is there a better method for this?

Regards.

Comment: I do not think lists, if used properly, suffer the limitations you are suggesting. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12772522/1201032

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
 x <- vector('list', 10)
```

since `vector` can create empty vector of the desired mode and length.

Answer taken from [earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464379/preallocate-list-in-r)