# Merging in R based on column and row

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

For a sample dataframe:

```
survey <- structure(list(id = 1:10, cntry = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("DE", "FR", "UK"), class = "factor"), 
    age.cat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Y_15.24", "Y_40.54", "Y_55.plus", "Y_less.15"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "cntry", "age.cat"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I want to add an extra column called 'age.cat' that is populated by another dataframe:

```
age.cat <- structure(list(cntry = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("DE", 
    "FR", "UK"), class = "factor"), Y_less.15 = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.3), 
        Y_15.24 = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.2), Y_25.39 = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1), Y_40.54 = c(0.3, 
        0.2, 0.1), Y_55.plus = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)), .Names = c("cntry", 
    "Y_less.15", "Y_15.24", "Y_25.39", "Y_40.54", "Y_55.plus"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -3L))
```

The age.cat dataframe lists proportions of people in the three countries by the different age categories.  The corresponding country/age category needs to be added as an additional column in the survey dataframe.  Previously, when I used a single country for example, I use merge, but this wouldn't work here as I understand as I need matching on a column and row.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `data.table`, I'd do this directly as follows:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
dt1[dt2, ratio := unlist(mget(age.cat)), by=.EACHI, on="cntry"]
```

where,

```
dt1 = as.data.table(survey)[, age.cat := as.character(age.cat)]
dt2 = as.data.table(age.cat)
```

For each row in `dt2`, the matching rows in `dt1$cntry` are found corresponding to `dt2$cntry` (it helps to think of it like a *subset* operation by matching on `cntry` column). `age.cat` values for those matching rows are extracted and passed to `mget()` function, that looks for variables named with the values in `age.cat`, and finds it in `dt2` (we allow for columns in `dt2` to be also visible for exactly this purpose), and extracts the corresponding values. Since it returns a `list`, we `unlist` it. Those values are assigned to the column `ratio` by reference.

Since this avoids unnecessary materialising of intermediate data by melting/gathering, it is quite efficient. Additionally, since it adds a new column by reference *while joining*, it avoids another intermediate materialisation and is doubly efficient.

Personally, I find the code much more straightforward to understand as to what's going on (with sufficient base R knowledge of course), but that is of course subjective.

---

#### Slightly more detailed explanation:

The general form of data.table syntax is `DT[i, j, by]` which reads:

> Take `DT`, subset rows by `i`, then compute `j` grouped by `by`.

The `i` argument in *data.table*, in addition to being subset operations e.g., `dt1[cntry == "FR"]`, can also be *another data.table*.

Consider the expression: `dt1[dt2, on="cntry"]`.

The first thing it does is to compute, for each row in `dt2`, all matching row indices in `dt1` by matching on the column provided in `on` = `"cntry"`. For example, for `dt2$cntry == "FR"`, the matching row indices in `dt1` are `c(1,4,5,10)`. These row indices are internally computed using fast binary search.

Once the matching row indices are computed it looks as to whether an expression is provided in the `j` argument. In the above expression `j` is empty. Therefore it returns all the columns from both `dt1` and `dt2` (leading to a right join).

In other words, data.table allows *join* operations to be performed in a similar fashion to *subsets* (because in both operations, the purpose of `i` argument is to obtain matching rows). For example, `dt1[cntry == "FR"]` would first compute the matching row indices, and then extract all columns for those rows (since no columns are provided in the `j` argument). This has several advantages. For example, if we would only like to return a subset of columns, then we can do, for example:

```
dt1[dt2, .(cntry, Y_less.15), on="cntry"]
```

This is efficient because we look at the `j` expression and notice that only those two columns are required. Therefore on the computed row indices, we only extract the required columns thereby avoiding unnecessary materialisation of all the other columns. Hence efficient

Also, just like how we can select columns, we can also *compute* on columns. For example, what if you'd like to get `sum(Y_less.15)`?

```
dt1[dt2, sum(Y_less.15), on="cntry"]
# [1] 2.3
```

This is great, but it computes the sum on *all the matching rows*. What if you'd like to get the `sum` *for each row in `dt2$cntry`*? This is where `by = .EACHI` comes in.

```
dt1[dt2, sum(Y_less.15), on="cntry", by=.EACHI]
#    cntry  V1
# 1:    FR 0.2
# 2:    UK 0.2
# 3:    DE 0.3
```

`by=.EACHI` ensures that the `j` expression is evaluated *for each row in `i = dt2`*.

Similarly, we can also *add/update* columns while joining using the `:=` operator. And that's the answer shown above. The only tricky part there is to extract the values for those matching rows from `dt2`, since they are stored in separate columns. Hence we use `mget()`. And the expression `unlist(mget(.))` gets evaluated for *each row in `dt2`* while matching on `"cntry"` column. And the corresponding values are assigned to `ratio` by using the `:=` operator.

> For more details on history of `:=` operator see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033106/why-has-data-table-defined-rather-than-overloading), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10225098/559784) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7029944/559784) post on SO.
>
> For more on `by=.EACHI`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004002/eachi-in-data-table/27004566#27004566).
>
> For more on data.table syntax introduction and reference semantics, see the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Hope this helps.

Comment: does := operation matches between each element ? %in% can also be used ?

Comment: @Learner, added a detailed explanation.

Comment: thanks but it is too long and made me confused even more! however, thanks for putting your effort to explain what := does and I liked you answer but made me more confused :-D

Comment: It's part of learning new concepts / ways of doing things. It's not necessarily a bad thing. I've provided additional link on `:=` to read upon if you're still curious.

Comment: I started learning data.table thanks to you , my first answer I used this package http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame/37443836#37443836

Answer (score 1):

We can do a join after `melt`ing the second dataset to 'long' format

```
library(data.table) #v1.9.7
melt(setDT(age.cat), id.var="cntry")[survey, on = c("cntry",  "variable" = "age.cat")]
#    cntry  variable value id
# 1:    FR   Y_15.24   0.2  1
# 2:    UK   Y_15.24   0.1  2
# 3:    DE   Y_40.54   0.1  3
# 4:    FR Y_less.15   0.2  4
# 5:    FR   Y_15.24   0.2  5
# 6:    UK Y_55.plus   0.2  6
# 7:    DE Y_less.15   0.3  7
# 8:    DE Y_less.15   0.3  8
# 9:    UK   Y_15.24   0.1  9
#10:    FR   Y_40.54   0.3 10
```

If we are using the CRAN version i.e. `data.table_1.9.6`,

```
melt(setDT(age.cat), id.var="cntry", variable.name = "age.cat")[survey, 
                        on = c("cntry",  "age.cat")]
```

Comment: @agenis Are you using the new version of data.table

Comment: @akrun I also got an error saying this Error in forderv(x, by = rightcols) : 
  'by' value -2147483648 out of range [1,3]

Comment: Perhaps with the version difference?  I am using `data.table_1.9.7`, but it should have worked with the CRAN version

Comment: @akrun > packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.9.6’

Comment: @Learner Updated the post.  I guess the option of using different column names with `on` is only available in the devel version

Comment: @akrun now works, one question , here you used the setDT(age.cat) to convert the age.cat to data.table or you did it for something else ?

Comment: @Learner Yes, I used that to convert to 'data.table'

Comment: @akrun I liked your answer then this could give the answer melt(setDT(age.cat), id.var="cntry") why did you add [survey, on = c("cntry",  "variable" = "age.cat")]

Comment: @Learner It is because the `melt` output by default gives the `variable` as the column name which is different from the column name in the second dataset i.e. `age.cat`

Answer (score 1):

You can turn age.cat into long format and then use join as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
age.cat <- gather(age.cat, age.cat, proportion, -cntry)
inner_join(survey, age.cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, using packages `reshape2` and `dplyr`:

```
age.cat %>% melt(variable.name="age.cat") %>% left_join(survey, .)
#### id cntry   age.cat value
#### 1  1    FR   Y_15.24   0.2
#### 2  2    UK   Y_15.24   0.1
#### 3  3    DE   Y_40.54   0.1
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: You could also use `tidyr::gather(age.cat, value, -cntry)` instead of `melt()`

Comment: @Steven Beauport what exactly this :: does ?

Comment: Have a look at https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-dblcolon.html