# Referencing a dataframe recursively

Tags: r, subset

Is there a way to have a dataframe refer to itself?

I find myself spending a lot of time writing things like `y$Category1[is.na(y$Category1)]<-NULL` which are hard to read and feel like a lot of slow repetitive typing. I wondered if there was something along the lines of:

`y$Category1[is.na(self)] <- NULL` I could use instead.

Thanks

Comment: `?with`, `?within`, `?transform`, `?subset`, and the `data.table` package will all be useful.

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker. Could you give some examples. I ask because `transform(airquality,is.na(Ozone)<-0)` or `with(airquality,is.na(Ozone) <- 0)` didn't work and I'm not clear how I'd use subset `x[match(subset(x,is.na(x)))]` .. but I think I've just confused myself. :-)

Comment: Read the help carefully for `transform`, the `...` must be in the form `tag = value`. This is a place where `<-` and `=` *are not* interchangeable.  `transform(airquality, Ozone = replace(Ozone, is.na(Ozone),0)` would work, as would `within(airquality, Ozone[is.na(Ozone)] <- 0)` (again, `<-` is important here, not `=`)

Comment: Here is a `data.table` example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768686/r-self-reference

Comment: I think the problem that @TahnoonPasha is trying to find a solution to is the repeated use of "Ozone" in this example.  The solutions here, while interesting, are even more verbose that the initial solution given above.  This has been a low-level annoyance for me too, and I would love to see a better solution.

Comment: Fundamentally, I think this is more a question about vectors than about data frames -- the operation is `numericVector[cond(numericVector)] <- newVal`, the data.frame portion of it is just a red herring.

Comment: @user295691 is right. I'd like to reduce the use of 'Ozone', in this case. The data frame piece is probably overspecified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What a great question.  Unfortunately, as @user295691 pointed out in the coments, the issue is with regards to referencing a vector twice: once as the object being indexed and once as the subject of a condition. It does appear impossible to avoid the double reference.

```
numericVector[cond(numericVector)] <- newVal
```

What I think we can do is have a nice and neat function so that instead of

```
 # this  
 y$Category1[is.na(y$Category1)] <- list(NULL)

 # we can have this: 
 NAtoNULL(y$Category1)
```

For example, the following functions wrap `selfAssign()` (below):

```
NAtoNULL(obj)      # Replaces NA values in obj with NULL.
NAtoVal(obj, val)  # Replaces NA values in obj with val.
selfReplace(obj, toReplace, val)  # Replaces toReplace values in obj with val

# and selfAssign can be called directly, but I'm not sure there would be a good reason to
selfAssign(obj, ind, val)  # equivalent to obj[ind] <- val
```

Example:

```
# sample df
df <- structure(list(subj=c("A",NA,"C","D","E",NA,"G"),temp=c(111L,112L,NA,114L,115L,116L,NA),size=c(0.7133,NA,0.7457,NA,0.0487,NA,0.8481)),.Names=c("subj","temp","size"),row.names=c(NA,-7L),class="data.frame")

df
  subj temp   size
1    A  111 0.7133
2 <NA>  112     NA
3    C   NA 0.7457
4    D  114     NA
5    E  115 0.0487
6 <NA>  116     NA
7    G   NA 0.8481

# Make some replacements
NAtoNULL(df$size)    # Replace all NA's in df$size wtih NULL's
NAtoVal(df$temp, 0)  # Replace all NA's in df$tmp wtih 0's
NAtoVal(df$subj, c("B", "E"))   # Replace all NA's in df$subj with alternating "B" and "E" 

# the modified df is now:  
df

  subj temp   size
1    A  111 0.7133
2    B  112   NULL
3    C    0 0.7457
4    D  114   NULL
5    E  115 0.0487
6    E  116   NULL
7    G    0 0.8481


# replace the 0's in temp for NA
selfReplace(df$temp, 0, NA)

# replace NULL's in size for 1's
selfReplace(df$size, NULL, 1)

# replace all "E"'s in subj with alternate c("E", "F")
selfReplace(df$subj, c("E"), c("E", "F"))

df

  subj temp   size
1    A  111 0.7133
2    B  112      1
3    C   NA 0.7457
4    D  114      1
5    E  115 0.0487
6    F  116      1
7    G   NA 0.8481
```

Right now this works for vectors, but will fail with *apply. I would love to get it working fully, especially with applying plyr. The key would be to modify

---

#### FUNCTIONS

The code for the functions are below.

An important point.  This does not (yet!) work with *apply / plyr.
I believe it can by modifying the value of n and adjusting `sys.parent(.)` in `match.call()` but it still needs some fiddling. 
Any suggestions / modifications would be grealy appreciated

```
selfAssign <- function(self, ind, val, n=1, silent=FALSE) {
## assigns val to self[ind] in environment parent.frame(n)
## self should be a vector.  Currently will not work for matricies or data frames

  ## GRAB THE CORRECT MATCH CALL
  #--------------------------------------
      # if nested function, match.call appropriately
      if (class(match.call()) == "call") {
        mc <- (match.call(call=sys.call(sys.parent(1))))
      } else {
        mc <- match.call()
      }

      # needed in case self is complex (ie df$name)
      mc2 <- paste(as.expression(mc[[2]]))


  ## CLEAN UP ARGUMENT VALUES
  #--------------------------------------
      # replace logical indecies with numeric indecies
      if (is.logical(ind))
        ind <- which(ind) 

      # if no indecies will be selected, stop here
      if(identical(ind, integer(0)) || is.null(ind)) {
        if(!silent) warning("No indecies selected")
        return()
      }

      # if val is a string, we need to wrap it in quotes
      if (is.character(val))
        val <- paste('"', val, '"', sep="")

      # val cannot directly be NULL, must be list(NULL)
      if(is.null(val))
        val <- "list(NULL)"


  ## CREATE EXPRESSIONS AND EVAL THEM
  #--------------------------------------
     # create expressions to evaluate
     ret <- paste0("'[['(", mc2, ", ", ind, ") <- ", val)

     # evaluate in parent.frame(n)
     eval(parse(text=ret), envir=parent.frame(n))
}


NAtoNULL <- function(obj, n=1) {
  selfAssign(match.call()[[2]], is.na(obj), NULL, n=n+1)
}

NAtoVal <- function(obj, val, n=1) {
  selfAssign(match.call()[[2]], is.na(obj), val, n=n+1)  
}

selfReplace <- function(obj, toReplace, val, n=1) {
## replaces occurrences of toReplace within obj with val

  # determine ind based on value & length of toReplace
  # TODO:  this will not work properly for data frames, but neither will selfAssign, yet.
  if (is.null(toReplace)) {
    ind <- sapply(obj, function(x) is.null(x[[1]]))
  }  else if (is.na(toReplace)) {
    ind <- is.na(obj)
  } else  {
    if (length(obj) > 1) {    # note, this wont work for data frames
          ind <- obj %in% toReplace
    } else {
      ind <- obj == toReplace
    }
  } 

  selfAssign(match.call()[[2]], ind, val, n=n+1)  
}



  ## THIS SHOULD GO INSIDE NAtoNULL, NAtoVal etc. 

  # todo: modify for use with *apply
  if(substr(paste(as.expression(x1)), 1, 10) == "FUN(obj = ") {
      # PASS.  This should identify when the call is coming from *apply. 
      #  in such a case, need to increase n by 1 for apply & lapply.  Increase n by 2 for sapply      
      # I'm not sure the increase required for plyr functions
  }
```

Comment: Amazing @RicardoSaporta This is just what I needed and is going into my preload file. Thank you.