# "self"-variable for easy referencing in R?

Tags: arrays, r, reference, self

I want to show only parts of an array, that has a long variable name. So far I used:

```
# Data
k0100_m020_r05_h10000__aea000_aee0$cumsumData = c(-1:10)

# show only parts
k0100_m020_r05_h10000__aea000_aee0$cumsumData[k0100_m020_r05_h10000__aea000_aee0$cumsumData>0]
```

I wonder if there is a shorter form, since I have to repeat the variable name within the square brackets. **Is there a shorter reference to the variable currently used?** e.g.:

```
k0100_m020_r05_h10000__aea000_aee0$cumsumData[_self>0]
```

Comment: Why don't you call the array (is it really an array or do you mean a dataframe, because the `$` operator doesn't work with matrices/arrays as far as I am aware) something else with a short name?  e.g. `mydat <- k0100_m020_r05_h10000__aea000_aee0`, then `mydat[mydat$cumsumData > 0 , ]`

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7768686/271616

Comment: I want to call the array without auxiliary variables. The more variables you have, the more confusing are the sourcecodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `subset`.

```
subset(k0100_m020_r05_h10000__aea000_aee0, cumsumData > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to want to look into more than one column an `apply` approach might be useful:

```
k0100_m020_r05_h10000__aea000_aee0 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5))

apply( k0100_m020_r05_h10000__aea000_aee0 , 2 , function(x) x [ x>0 ] )
#$V1
#[1] 1.5840356 0.2497689

#$V2
#[1] 0.4179352 1.6187143 0.8245239

#$V3
#[1] 0.09328116 0.20761514 0.29894603 2.14484045

#$V4
#[1] 0.4882152 0.4643691 0.5591095

#$V5
#[1] 1.0749748 0.5405291 0.4899797 1.0828021
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is what you want, but perhaps `with()` can help:

```
mask <- with(k0100_m020_r05_h10000__aea000_aee0, _self > 0) # gives you a boolean vector
k0100_m020_r05_h10000__aea000_aee0[mask]                    # gives you the result
```