# r - difficult to understand structure of empty columns filled with dates

Tags: r, as.date

I have a data frame with empty columns. I want to fill one row of that data frame with dates.

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = rep(NA, 2), c = rep(NA, 2))
mydates <- as.Date(c("2016-01-31", "2016-02-29"))
x[1, c("b", "c")] <- mydates
x
str(x)
```

My dates appear in the first row as numeric values and columns b and c are numeric now. Clearly not what I want.

How about this:

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = rep(NA, 2), c = rep(NA, 2))
for (v in c("b", "c")) x[[v]] <- as.Date(x[[v]])
x
str(x)
x[1, c("b", "c")] <- mydates
```

Although I declared my variables as dates, it's not working.

What works is:

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = rep(NA, 2), c = rep(NA, 2))
x
x[1, c("b", "c")] <- mydates
x
for (v in c("b", "c")) x[[v]] <- as.Date(x[[v]])
x
str(x)
```

Could anyone please explain what exactly is going on and why the 3rd block of code works but the second doesn't? In fact, I am not even sure why the first block of code isn't working...

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would probably have initialized the b & c columns as NA dates and then tried to insert a data frame of dates, not a vector.

Comment: All you need to do is wrap your `rep` calls in `as.Date()`

Comment: @RichScriven No, if I wrap my rep calls in as.Date() I am getting the same problem as in Block 2: Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: @joran That's what happens in my Block 2 - it's not working.

Comment: None of your code blocks do what I suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, there is a need to set the class of the columns to Date. But it's also helpful to pass these values as a named list.

```
> x <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = as.Date(rep(NA, 2)), c = as.Date(rep(NA, 2)))
> x
  a    b    c
1 1 <NA> <NA>
2 2 <NA> <NA>
> x[1, c("b", "c")] <- list( b= as.Date(c("2016-01-31"), c=as.Date("2016-02-29")) )
> x
  a          b          c
1 1 2016-01-31 2016-01-31
2 2       <NA>       <NA>
> str(x)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2
 $ b: Date, format: "2016-01-31" NA
 $ c: Date, format: "2016-01-31" NA
```

Here's a more complicated test of the method I'm suggesting (since I got tired of waiting for you to post a more complicated example in code):

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = as.Date(rep(NA, 3)), c = as.Date(rep(NA, 3)))
x
#----------
  a    b    c
1 1 <NA> <NA>
2 2 <NA> <NA>
3 3 <NA> <NA>
#---
x[1:2, c("b", "c")] <- list( b= as.Date(c("2016-01-31", "2020-02-09"), c=as.Date("2016-02-29", "2027-08-22")) )
x
#####
  a          b          c
1 1 2016-01-31 2016-01-31
2 2 2020-02-09 2020-02-09
3 3       <NA>       <NA>
```

This is reminding me of an earlier answer to a somewhat different question that I posted which was inspired by a comment from Gabor Grothendeick (which I will now attempt to track down.) Found it; The last of my examples shows how to use logical tests as the "indexing" for assignments to "blocks" of items in a  dataframe: [R self reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768686/r-self-reference/7769296?r=SearchResults&s=1|41.6199#7769296)

Comment: Thank you and I apologize - I slightly updated my question. In real life, my dates are saved in a vector mydates. And your solution with the list - while it's very nice - is not working when I have a vector mydates. list(mydates) is not working.

Comment: You need to show with code what is "not working" Your update does not appear to do so.

Comment: My 3rd block of code is working. My question was rather - why doesn't the 2nd one work?

Comment: @user3245256 There isn't going to be a terribly satisfying explanation beyond "inserting a list rather than a vector avoids some coercion pathways in `[<-.data.frame`". The basic lesson is that you can't expect to do rowwise insertions on data frames with vectors and have things work the way you expect in all cases.

Comment: @joran OK, I understand, however, I am still not having an example of a solution with a list that is using mydates.

Comment: @user3245256 The above answer is a solution using a list. The idea is that instead of creating `mydates` with `c()` you create it with `list()`. Or possibly convert it to a list via `as.list()`.

Comment: @joran Thank you, as.list worked! So, the solution is: x <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = as.Date(rep(NA, 3)), c = as.Date(rep(NA, 3))); mydates <- as.list(as.Date(c("2016-01-31", "2020-02-09"))); x[1:2, c("b", "c")] <- mydates

Comment: @joran Could you please amend your response using mydates (as in my previous comment) so that I could accept your answer? Thank you!

Comment: @user3245256 I would just accept this one, it is identical to what I suggested.