# Aggregate function with cbind

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm trying to use the `aggregate` function with `cbind`, but I must be missing something.

I've seen in [Using Aggregate for Multiple Aggregations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064202/r-using-aggregate-for-multiple-aggregations) that I can simply define which column I want to be fixed and which I'd like to add, but I just can't get the result I expected.

I have:

```
x <- data.frame(alfa = 1:9, beta = rep(1:3, 3))

  alfa beta
1    1    1
2    2    2
3    3    3
4    4    1
5    5    2
6    6    3
7    7    1
8    8    2
9    9    3
```

And I want to retrieve the mean of the entries aggregated by the ones in column *beta*. For that I've tried:

```
aggregate(cbind(alfa) ~ beta, data = x, FUN = function(x) c(gama = mean(x)) )
```

That gives me:

```
  beta alfa
1    1    4
2    2    5
3    3    6
```

Shouldn't the result be something like:

```
  alfa beta gama
1    1    1    4
2    2    2    5
3    3    3    6
```

How do I force the addition of column *gama*? Additionally, would someone clarify the basis of the `cbind()` function? I've been struggling to understand it. Regards!

Comment: By what rule would you want to get the alfa column to be computed?

Comment: I thought it'd simply maintain the first entry of each group, in a sql fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aggregate takes all elements on the left side of the `~` and uses the given function on those values, while they are grouped by the values of the right side. 
Thus, your command

```
aggregate(alfa ~ beta, data=x, mean)
```

will return the mean values of `alfa` grouped by `beta`. (As you mentioned SQL - this is the same as will happen with the SQL-clause `SELECT beta, avg(alfa) FROM x GROUP BY beta`)

If you want to output the first value encountered, this basically is another aggregation that you want to do, thus your aggregation function has to return two values:

```
aggregate(alfa ~ beta, data=x, function(x) c(alfa=x[1], gamma=mean(x)))
```

(Again in SQL: `SELECT beta, min(alfa), avg(alfa) FROM x GROUP BY beta`)

You asked about the `cbind`. As long as you have only one argument on the left hand side, this does not matter at all. But suppose you have the following situation:

```
x <- data.frame(alfa = 1:9, beta = rep(1:3, 3), gamma = rnorm(9))
```

and would like to compute, say, the mean of both columns `alfa` and `gamma`, you could do it like this:

```
aggregate(cbind(alfa, gamma) ~ beta, data=x, function(x) mean(x))
```

That way you just tell the aggregate function to use throw `alfa` and `gamma` both at the given function.

For more and exhaustive examples, see `?aggregate`.

---

### Edit

You have to be careful not to mix different meanings of `cbind`. Used a separate function, it concats two vectors (or data.frames) of the same length to a matrix (or data.frame) with both inputs as different columns:

```
> cbind(1:3, 7:9)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    7
[2,]    2    8
[3,]    3    9
```

Used in the formula notation of aggregate `cbind` does something related but yet different. `cbind(column1, column2)` just tells aggregate to use the given function on both rows *seperately*. Thus, something like

```
aggregate(cbind(alfa, gamma) ~ beta, data=x, function(x) mean(x[,1]*x[,2]))
```

will *not* work. Rather, the function will be called two times - once with the values of `alfa`, then with the values of `beta`.

Hope that clarifies your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works now. And now i understand the application of this cbind() function. Just confirming, cbind() converts the arguments into an unique c() structure, that could be indexed inside function(x), right?