# Multiple aggregation with arithmetic on LHS in R formula

Tags: r, aggregate

Anybody have any bright ideas on how to do multiple aggregations such as sum and mean with arithmetic on the left hand side of the formula, something like this:

```
aggregate(A+B ~ C, data=D, FUN=c(sum, mean))
```

I expect a 3 column result with  C, mean(A+B) and sum(A+B).

I've looked at summaryBy from the 'doBy' package but it fails with the arithmetic.

The closest I've found is to create a custom function taking a param and then applying the 2 aggregation functions within it, however, the result is still a bit messy to work with as there are 2 columns, the second containing a list with both aggregations.

```
aggregate(A+B ~ C, data = D, FUN=function(x) c(s=sum(x), m=mean(x)))
```

It's tedious, verbose and more computationally expensive doing two aggregations across the same data and then merging those aggregations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
set.seed(1)
D <- data.frame(A=rpois(100,1),B=rpois(100,1),C=rep(1:10,each=10))
result <- aggregate(A+B ~ C, data = D, FUN=function(x) c(s=sum(x), m=mean(x)))
result <- data.frame(result[,1],result[,2])
```

There is indeed an extra step to get the 3-column data frame, but this does not require multiple aggregation or merge.

Incidentally, the problem you point out, regarding the way `aggregate(...)` deals with functions that return vectors, applies not just for formulas with an expression on the LHS.

```
result <- aggregate(A ~ C, data = D, FUN=function(x) c(s=sum(x), m=mean(x)))
```

returns a *2 column* data frame, where each element in the second column contains a vector of length 2, but if you display `result` you are led to believe that `result` has three columns

```
head(result)
#   C  A.s  A.m
# 1 1 11.0  1.1
# 2 2 13.0  1.3
# 3 3  8.0  0.8
# 4 4 10.0  1.0
# 5 5 12.0  1.2
# 6 6  7.0  0.7
str(result)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ C: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ A: num [1:10, 1:2] 11 13 8 10 12 7 9 13 6 12 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : NULL
#   .. ..$ : chr  "s" "m"
```

Comment: If only I thought like you - simply. Your solution indeed does what I am looking for.
I found a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064202/using-aggregate-for-multiple-aggregations) which I didn't investigate further - sorry about that- this lead to the slightly more generic version of your above solution.
`as.data.frame(as.list(aggregate(A+B ~ C, data = D, FUN=function(x) c(s=sum(x), m=mean(x)))))`
Thanks for your response, think I'll mark this as the solution as it best answers how I thought about this.
But the dplyr answer below is very intriguing as well.

Comment: I think it's also useful to note - as seen in solution link from previous comment- that using the cbind rules on the left hand side allows one to rename the colums as follows. `cbind(my_name_instead_of_a_plus_b=A+B)`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `dplyr` like so:

```
require(dplyr)

D %>% 
  group_by(C) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(A+B), 
            mean = mean(A+B))
```

With sample data:

```
set.seed(99)
D <- data.frame(A = runif(10), B = runif(10), C= sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, TRUE))
D %>% group_by(C) %>% summarise(sum = sum(A+B), mean = mean(A+B))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#
#  C      sum      mean
#1 A 3.596430 0.7192861
#2 B 3.236218 1.6181089
#3 C 2.498058 0.8326859
```

Comment: This is very interesting, I will have to investigate the dplyr package in more depth. Thanks for taking the time to give your response :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems not so bad to me. The formation of the aggregate values as a matrix column of the result is actually convenient since one can refer to the jth aggregate as `DF[[2]][j]` rather than resorting to index arithmetic.

At any rate here is a function that will do it the way you want:

```
myag <- function(formula, data, FUN) {
   .FUN <- function(x) sapply(FUN, function(f) match.fun(f)(x))
   do.call("data.frame", c(aggregate(formula, data, .FUN), check.names = FALSE) )
}

# test it
ag <-    myag(mpg + wt ~ cyl, mtcars, c("mean", "sum"))
```

giving:

```
> ag
  cyl mpg + wt.mean mpg + wt.sum
1   4      28.94936      318.443
2   6      22.86000      160.020
3   8      19.09921      267.389
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was trying to avoid creating new functions as I was looking for something I could rely on everywhere - that I wouldn't have to recreate or maintain :)