# Concatenate lists with override in R

Tags: r

How do I concatenate two lists in R in such a way that duplicate elements from the second one will override corresponding elements from the first one?

I tried `c()`, but it keeps duplicates:

```
l1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
l1 <- c(l1, list(b = 3, c = 4))

# $a
# [1] 1
# 
# $b
# [1] 2
# 
# $b
# [1] 3
#
# $c
# [1] 4
```

I want something that will produce this instead:

```
# $a
# [1] 1
# 
# $b
# [1] 3
#
# $c
# [1] 4
```

Hope that there exists something simpler than calling some *apply function?

Comment: TMS, Do none of the solutions below work for you? How about `modifyList` as the base R approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you could get the behavior you want by using the "rlist" package; specifically, `list.merge` seems to do what you are looking for:

```
l1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
l2 <- list(b = 3, c = 4)
library(rlist)
list.merge(l1, l2)
# $a
# [1] 1
# 
# $b
# [1] 3
# 
# $c
# [1] 4
```

Try `list.merge(l2, l1)` to get a sense of the function's behavior.

---

If you have just two lists, as noted by @PeterDee, the `list.merge` function pretty much makes `modifyList` accept more than two lists. Thus, for this particular example, you could skip loading any packages and directly do:

```
modifyList(l1, l2)
```

Comment: This is great - it is built on top of `utils::modifyList`.

Comment: That's it! This should be in the base R :-)

Comment: @TMS, it sort of *is* in base R. See the update at the end of my answer, in reference to PeterDee's comment.

Comment: `modifyList` is the way to go!

Answer (score 5):

This works with `duplicated`:

```
> l1[!duplicated(names(l1), fromLast=TRUE)]
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 3

$c
[1] 4
```

Comment: thanks this works, but I would still hope for something simpler for such a basic thing...

Comment: @TMS what could be possibly simpler than just use `duplicated` combined with simple subsetting? Did you ever see anything simpler in another language? This code will be also very efficient.

Comment: perhaps something like `l1 + l2`? :-) I mean, this feels so basic that there should be an operator for that.

Comment: @TMS, why would this be a `+` condition? If you're not happy with the other straightforward and standard ways of achieving what you want, you might just have to write the solution yourself. If you are [unhappy with how something is designed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27943961/1270695) and others offer you solutions that are efficient and work *but you are still unhappy because it doesn't work using your expected syntax*, then you're the best one to try to make your expected syntax work by writing your own function or method or operator or something else. :-/

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a quicker way than:

```
l1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
l2 <- list(b = 3, c = 4)

l1 <- c(l1[!(names(l1) %in% names(l2))],  l2)
```

You take the names of the `l1` that are not in `l2` and concatenate the two lists

Comment: thanks this works, but I would still hope for something simpler for such a basic thing...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `union`:

```
l1 <- list(a = 1, b = 3)
l2 <- list(b = 3, c = 4)

union(l1, l2)
```

This works like a union in mathematics ([Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29))

Comment: Yes -- this is the output I get:
   [[1]]
   [1] 1
    
   [[2]]
   [1] 3
    
  [[3]]
  [1] 4