# Crosstable with two variables that displays (only) the mean, standard deviation and samplesize of a third variable in R

Tags: r, stata, crosstab

i'm searching for an easy way to create a multivariat crosstable with two variables that only displays the mean, standard deviation and frequencies/samplesize **of a third** variable. In the best case with column sums and row sums.

Example with the mtcars dataset (table with "cyl" and "vs"; mean, standard deviation and frequencies of "hp"):
In Stata it would be `tabulate cyl vs, summarize(hp) freq mean sta`.

[To make clear how it ideally should look like I've made an example (the results are just made up):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MaLb.png)

or

[Example 2 (results also just made up)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44WLE.png)

(Finally I have to transfer the table to LaTeX - ideally with stargazer - so it would be best of all if this were possible.)

I found a lot of solutions for crosstables with means, but only for two variables. And certainly not with mean, std. dev. and frequencies in one table. You would be a huge help to me.

edit: Now I tried this, but I don't know how to add standard deviation, column sums and row sums.

```
    library(tidyr)

ct <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, vs) %>%
  summarise(hp = mean(hp, na.rm=TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
  spread(vs, hp)
ct

ct %>%
  adorn_rounding() %>%
  adorn_ns(
    ns = mtcars %>% # calculate the Ns on the fly by calling tabyl on the original data
      tabyl(cyl, vs)
  ) %>%
  adorn_title("combined", row_name = "Cylinders", col_name = "Is Automatic")

# stargazer(ct)
```

And I get this (means by group and frequencies in brackets):

```
  Cylinders/Is Automatic          0          1
1                      4    91  (1)  81.8 (10)
2                      6 131.7  (3) 115.2  (4)
3                      8 209.2 (14)    NA  (0)
```

edit2:

```
library(tidyr)
library(arsenal)
tab1 <- tableby(vs ~ hp, data=mtcars, strata = cyl, numeric.stats = c("meansd", "N"), test = FALSE)
summary(tab1, text = TRUE)
```

This sort of works for me, but to get the exact table - as in my illustration - into LaTeX, I unfortunately have to do a lot of work by hand.

Unfortunately `stargazer(tab1)` does not work at all, because of

> % Error: Unrecognized object type.

.

`summary(tab1, text = "latex")` does work, but as mentioned to get a more or less beautiful, publication quality table in LaTeX there's a lot of work by hand.
Maybe it's too much to ask, but does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It might come in handy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65358012/r-equivalent-of-table-contents-stata-command-for-summary-statistics and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66479635/crosstable-with-multiple-items-in-rows-and-columns

Answer (score 3):

Several packages in R could be helpful. The one I have used is `arsenal` which may be close to `Stata tabulate, summarize`

```r
library(tidyr)
library(arsenal)
tab1 <- tableby(vs ~ hp, data=mtcars, strata = cyl,
                numeric.stats = c("meansd", "N"), test = FALSE)
summary(tab1, text = TRUE)
#> 
#> 
#> |cyl |             |     0 (N=18)     |    1 (N=14)     |   Total (N=32)   |
#> |:---|:------------|:----------------:|:---------------:|:----------------:|
#> |4   |hp           |                  |                 |                  |
#> |    |-  Mean (SD) |   91.000 (NA)    | 81.800 (21.872) | 82.636 (20.935)  |
#> |    |-  N         |        1         |       10        |        11        |
#> |6   |hp           |                  |                 |                  |
#> |    |-  Mean (SD) | 131.667 (37.528) | 115.250 (9.179) | 122.286 (24.260) |
#> |    |-  N         |        3         |        4        |        7         |
#> |8   |hp           |                  |                 |                  |
#> |    |-  Mean (SD) | 209.214 (50.977) |       NA        | 209.214 (50.977) |
#> |    |-  N         |        14        |        0        |        14        |
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you!
It sort of works for me, but to get the exact table - as in my illustration - into LaTeX, I unfortunately have to do a lot of work by hand.

Unfortunately `stargazer(tab1)` does not work at all, because of "% Error: Unrecognized object type.". 

`summary(tab1, text = "latex")` does work, but as mentioned to get a almost beautiful, publication quality table in LaTeX there's a lot of work by hand.
Maybe it's too much to ask, but does anyone have any ideas?