# Why do we need to convert a dataframe to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I came across this piece of code

```
...
temp <- as.data.frame(aggregate(Petal.Width~Species, iris, mean))
...
```

My question is: `aggregate(Petal.Width~Species, iris, mean)` was already a dataframe, what was the need for `as.data.frame()` then?

Comment: This indeed looks redundant. However, consider this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27945643/6574038

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf. How could you find such a relevant example like that?