# Results from aggregate with multiple functions not usable in further calculations. WHY?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a problem regarding results from an aggregate function in R. My aim is to select certain bird species from a data set and calculate the density
of observed individuals over the surveyed area. To that end, I took a subset of the main data file, then aggregated over area, calculating the
mean, and the number of individuals (represented by length of vector). Then I wanted to use the calculated mean area and number of individuals to
calculate density. That didn't work. The code I used is given below:

```
> head(data)

  positionmonth positionyear quadrant           Species  Code sum_areainkm2

1             5         2014        1 Bar-tailed Godwit  5340      155.6562

2             5         2014        1 Bar-tailed Godwit  5340      155.6562

3             5         2014        1 Bar-tailed Godwit  5340      155.6562

4             5         2014        1 Bar-tailed Godwit  5340      155.6562

5             5         2014        1            Gannet   710      155.6562

6             5         2014        1 Bar-tailed Godwit  5340      155.6562


sub.gannet<-subset(data, species == "Gannet")

sub.gannet<-data.frame(sub.gannet)


x<-sub.gannet

aggr.gannet<-aggregate(sub.gannet$sum_areainkm2, by=list(sub.gannet$positionyear, sub.gannet$positionmonth, sub.gannet$quadrant, sub.gannet$Species, sub.gannet$Code), FUN=function(x) c(observed_area=mean(x), NoInd=length(x)))

names(aggr.gannet)<-c("positionyear", "positionmonth", "quadrant", "species", "code", "x")

aggr.gannet<-data.frame(aggr.gannet)


> aggr.gannet

  positionyear positionmonth quadrant species code x.observed_area x.NoInd

1         2014             5        4  Gannet  710         79.8257 10.0000


density <- c(aggr.gannet$x.NoInd/aggr.gannet$x.observed_area)

aggr.gannet <- cbind(aggr.gannet, density)

Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 

  Arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

> density

numeric(0)

> aggr.gannet$x.observed_area

NULL

> aggr.gannet$x.NoInd

NULL
```

R doesn't seem to view the results from the function (observed_area and NoInd) as numeric values in their own right. That was already apparent, when I couldn't give them a name each, but had to call them "x".

How can I calculate density under these circumstances? Or is there another way to aggregate with multiple functions over the same variable that will result in a usable output?

Comment: Maybe look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32616751/1191259

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a quirk of aggregate with multiple aggregations that the resulting aggregations are stored in a list within the column related to the aggregated variable.

The easiest way to get rid of this is to go through an `as.list` before `as.dataframe`, which flattens the data structure.

```
aggr.gannet <- as.data.frame(as.list(aggr.gannet))
```

It will still use `x` as the name.  The way I discovered to fix this is to use the formula interface to `aggregate`, so your aggregate would look more like

```
aggr.gannet<-aggregate(
  sum_areainkm2 ~ positionyear + positionmonth +
    quadrant + Species + Code,
  data=sub.gannet,
  FUN=function(x) c(observed_area=mean(x), NoInd=length(x)))
```

Walking it through (here I haven't taken the subset to illustrate the aggregation by species)

```
df <- structure(list(positionmonth = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), positionyear = c(2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L), quadrant = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Bar-tailed Godwit", "Gannet"), class = "factor"), Code = c(5340L, 5340L, 5340L, 5340L, 710L, 5340L), sum_areainkm2 = c(155.6562, 155.6562, 155.6562, 155.6562, 155.6562, 155.6562)), .Names = c("positionmonth", "positionyear", "quadrant", "Species", "Code", "sum_areainkm2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df.agg <- as.data.frame(as.list(aggregate(
      sum_areainkm2 ~ positionyear + positionmonth +
        quadrant + Species + Code,
      data=df,
      FUN=function(x) c(observed_area=mean(x), NoInd=length(x)))))
```

Which results in what you want:

```
> df.agg
  positionyear positionmonth quadrant           Species Code
1         2014             5        1            Gannet  710
2         2014             5        1 Bar-tailed Godwit 5340
  sum_areainkm2.observed_area sum_areainkm2.NoInd
1                    155.6562                   1
2                    155.6562                   5
> names(df.agg)
[1] "positionyear"                "positionmonth"
[3] "quadrant"                    "Species"
[5] "Code"                        "sum_areainkm2.observed_area"
[7] "sum_areainkm2.NoInd"
```

Obligatory note here, that `dplyr` and `data.table` are powerful libraries that allow doing this sort of aggregation very simply and efficiently.

## dplyr

Dplyr has some strange syntax (the `%>%` operator), but ends up being quite readable, and allows chaining more complex operations

```
> require(dplyr)
> df %>%
  group_by(positionyear, positionmonth, quadrant, Species, Code) %>%
  summarise(observed_area=mean(sum_areainkm2), NoInd = n())
```

## data.table

data.table has a more compact syntax and may be faster with large datasets.

```
dt[,
  .(observed_area=mean(sum_areainkm2), NoInd=.N),
  by=.(positionyear, positionmonth, quadrant, Species, Code)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The first option worked a treat and I ended up using that, because it required minimal changes to my code and no extra package. I did try out the other two options as well and the dplyr and data.table worked perfectly. So three good options there.