# Too many variables to group and many variable to produce mean

Tags: r

I have many variables to group and produce mean value. I have given the r code below. Any other way to give the code short.

```
a<-b %>%
group_by(c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l) %>%
summarize(numbobs =n(),m= mean(m),n= mean(n),o= mean(o),p= mean(p),q= mean(q),r= mean(r)s= mean(s))
```

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus Don't you think it is different from the dupe link as this also include `numobs` and passing variables etc..

Comment: @akrun you are correct, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064202/using-aggregate-to-apply-several-functions-on-several-variables-in-one-call) is better I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a couple of things to make it short.

1) By using `group_by_`, we can group by many variables by passing an object that have the column names ('nm1')

2) Use `summarise_each` for applying the same function (`mean`) to multiple columns.

```
nm1 <- letters[3:12]
b %>%
   group_by_(.dots = nm1) %>%
   mutate(n = n()) %>%
   group_by(n, add=TRUE) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(mean), m:s)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(rnorm(10000*7), nrow=10000, dimnames = list(NULL, letters[13:19]))
set.seed(42)
m2 <- matrix(sample(letters[1:5], 10000*10, replace=TRUE), nrow=10000, 
         dimnames = list(NULL, letters[3:12]))
b <- cbind(as.data.frame(m2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE), m1)
b[3:5, 1:10] <- b[1, 1:10]
```

Comment: I gave the letters as an example...in the case of real time variable?

Comment: @111111  You can use `nm1 <- names(b)[1:10]` or change the index accordingly