# Summarise for multiple group_by variables combined and individually

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using dplyr's group_by and summarise to get a mean by each group_by variable combined, but also want to get the mean by each group_by variable individually.

For example if I run

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, vs) %>% 
  summarise(new = mean(wt))
```

I get

```
    cyl    vs      new
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
     4     0 2.140000
     4     1 2.300300
     6     0 2.755000
     6     1 3.388750
     8     0 3.999214
```

But I want to get

```
    cyl    vs      new
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
     4     0 2.140000
     4     1 2.300300
     4    NA 2.285727
     6     0 2.755000
     6     1 3.388750
     6    NA 3.117143
     8     0 3.999214
    NA     0 3.688556
    NA     1 2.611286
```

I.e. get the mean for the variables both combined and individually

**Edit** 
Jaap marked this as duplicate and pointed me in the direction of [Using aggregate to apply several functions on several variables in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064202/using-aggregate-to-apply-several-functions-on-several-variables-in-one-call). I looked at jaap's answer there which referenced dplyr but I can't see how that answers my question? You say to use `summarise_each`, but I still don't see how I can use that to get the mean of each of my group by variables individually? Apologies if I am being stupid...

Comment: i think you should try this you have to factorize your grouping variables.                                                                    mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl=as.factor(cyl),vs=as.factor(vs)) %>%
  group_by(cyl,vs) %>%
  summarise(new=mean(wt))

Comment: It's working fine.

Comment: Running the above still only shows the means of `cyl` and `vs` combined, and not individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea using `bind_rows`,

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
     group_by(cyl, vs) %>% 
     summarise(new = mean(wt)) %>% 
    bind_rows(., 
              mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(new = mean(wt)) %>% mutate(vs = NA), 
              mtcars %>% group_by(vs) %>% summarise(new = mean(wt)) %>% mutate(cyl = NA)) %>% 
   arrange(cyl) %>% 
   ungroup()

# A tibble: 10 × 3
#     cyl    vs      new
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1      4     0 2.140000
#2      4     1 2.300300
#3      4    NA 2.285727
#4      6     0 2.755000
#5      6     1 3.388750
#6      6    NA 3.117143
#7      8     0 3.999214
#8      8    NA 3.999214
#9     NA     0 3.688556
#10    NA     1 2.611286
```

Comment: Thanks, was hoping there'd me an argument in the group_by which allows you to do this, but with the lack of that I guess this is the quickest and easiest method