# select the latest date in the same column and sum value

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table, data-manipulation

I don't know how to name the proper title; however, following is my question.
I have a data:

```
ID    Name    Type    Date          Amount
1     AAAA    First   2009/7/20     100
1     AAAA    First   2010/2/3      200
2     BBBB    First   2015/3/10     250
2     CCC     Second  2009/2/23     300
2     CCC     Second  2010/1/25     400
2     CCC     Third   2015/4/9      500
2     CCC     Third   2016/6/25     700
```

I want to remove the data that has same `ID`, `Name`, and `Type`; but the `Date` is smaller. Or you can say that keep `Date` is the largest.
The result is like:

```
ID    Name    Type    Date        Amount  
1     AAAA    First   2010/2/3    300
2     BBBB    First   2015/3/10   250
2     CCC     Second  2010/1/25   700
2     CCC     Third   2016/6/25   1200
```

I know I can use `duplicated()` to get the which observations are duplicating.

```
dt <- fread("
        ID    Name    Type    Date
        1     AAAA    First   2009/7/20
        1     AAAA    First   2010/2/3
        2     BBBB    First   2015/3/10
        2     CCC     Second  2009/2/23
        2     CCC     Second  2010/1/25
        2     CCC     Third   2015/4/9
        2     CCC     Third   2016/6/25
        ")
dt$Date <- as.Date(dt$Date)
dt[duplicated(ID) & duplicated(Name) & duplicated(Type)]
   ID Name   Type      Date   Amount
1:  1 AAAA  First  2010/2/3   200
2:  2  CCC Second 2010/1/25   400
3:  2  CCC  Third 2016/6/25   700
```

However, this is not I want. Although it removes the smaller `Date`, it cannot keep the third observation(`ID`=2, `Name`=BBBB, `Type`=First). Also, I still need to sum  `Amount`.

How can I do?

Comment: @RonakShah - `as.Date(Date)` will be a problem here - is `2010/2/3` the 3rd of Feb or the 2nd of March? You might want to put an explicit format on that variable.

Comment: `unique(dt, by=c("ID","Name","Type"), fromLast=TRUE)` if you've sorted. You should use a proper date type, not a string, btw.

Comment: Sorry, I edit my question. I miss some important points,

Comment: Ok, then `.(last(Date), sum(Amount)), by=cols` like any other aggregation..? If so, someone could probably close this against https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/ which has a nice answer by Matt

Comment: In `dplyr`, `df %>%
  group_by(ID, Name, Type) %>%
  summarise(Date = max(as.Date(Date, "%Y/%m/%d")), 
            Amount = sum(Amount))`

Comment: @Frank `last()` is a `data.table` function?

Comment: Yes, and it's optimized in this case too. The `?GForce` doc explains, if you're interested. If it's not sorted, `max` works, too, of course.

Comment: I use `dt[, .(dplyr::summarise(Date = max(as.Date(Date, "%Y/%m/%d")), Amount = sum(Amount))), by = .(ID, Name, Type)]` but get error. How can I figure out it?

Comment: oh. I figure it out. `dt[,.(max(Date) ,Amount = sum(Amount)), by = .(ID, Name, Type)]` is correct.