# Weighted mean of duplicated columns

Tags: r

I have df:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5)
y <- c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4)
freq <- c(4,6,7,2,2,6,5,1)
distmean <-c(2,4,5,7,3,5,2,7)
df <- data.frame(x,y,freq,distmean)


x      y   freq   distmean
1      1      4          2
1      1      6          4 
2      2      7          5
2      3      2          7
3      3      2          3
3      3      6          5 
4      4      5          2 
5      4      1          7
```

I want to aggregate the rows based on `x` and `y`, with the sum of `freq` and a mean of `distmean` weighted by `freq`.

So in the end I want:

```
x      y   freq    distmean
1      1     10         3.2
2      2      7         5.0
2      3      2         7.0
3      3      8         4.5
4      4      5         2.0 
5      4      1         7.0
```

I tried using `aggregate()` which I can combine the duplicated rows with, but can't figure out a weighted mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using aggregate to apply several functions on several variables in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064202/using-aggregate-to-apply-several-functions-on-several-variables-in-one-call)

Comment: How do you calculate `distmean` ?

Comment: @RonakShah - `weighted.mean(distmean,freq)` I assume

Comment: I thought too. Ok, so `df %>%
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  summarise(freq_1 = sum(freq), 
            dist_mean = weighted.mean(distmean, freq))
` should give it.

Comment: Yep, and data.table is nearly identical `df[ , .(freq=sum(freq), distmean=weighted.mean(distmean,freq)), by=.(x,y)]`

Comment: Thanks! @RonakShah your solution worked. Simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a short method to do this. But can be done this way if you want to avoid complex functions.

`df2=a=aggregate(freq ~ x+y, data=df, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
df$dist=df$distmean*df$freq
b=aggregate(dist ~ x+y, data=df, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
df2$distmean=(b/a)[3]`