# How do I aggregate by group and add the column to the dataframe?

Tags: r, aggregate

Working with this [data](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/Card1995.Rdata) in Rstudio. I need to create a new df with the mean of `lwage76` grouped  by `ed76` and `regional.dummies`; also, the df needs to contain the sum of observations in those respective groups. This is what I have so far:

```
agglwage <- aggregate(lwage76 ~ regional.dummies + ed76, nlsdata, mean) 
 head(agglwage )

#    regional.dummies ed76  lwage76
#1                  7    1 6.214608
#2                  6    2 5.682503
#3                  2    3 5.746203
```

So far so good.

```
dfcount <- count(nlsdata, c("regional.dummies", "ed76"))                                                                                                                                     
head(dfcount, n=3)

#  regional.dummies ed76 freq
#1                1    7    2
#2                1    9    4
#3                1   10    6
```

I think I can probably merge the two df's now, but I think there must be a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: [Relevant link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064202/using-aggregate-to-apply-several-functions-on-several-variables-in-one-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'regional.dummies' and 'ed76', get the number of rows (`n()`) and `mean` of 'lwage76'

```
library(dplyr)
nlsdata %>%
      group_by(regional.dummies, ed76) %>%    
      summarise(freq = n(), lwage76 = mean(lwage76, na.rm = TRUE))
```