# Combining two rows in R

Tags: r, aggregate

This is a snippit of my data

```
Aaron Brook   450 36 25 .124 .530
Arron Afflalo 980 25 40 .128 .597
Arron Afflalo 236 25 94 .223 .621
```

I'm trying to combine the Arron Afflalo rows but at the same time adding column 1-3 but taking the mean of columns 4-5.

So the final data output looks like

```
Arron Afflalo 1216 50 134 .176 .609
```

Is there any quick way to do this. If not, is there a way just to delete all duplicate rows?

Comment: This is easy to do in `data.table`. `library(data.table) setDT(df) df[,.(sum(col1),sum(col2),sum(col3),mean(col4),mean(col5)), by=name_col]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply several summary functions on several variables by group in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064202/apply-several-summary-functions-on-several-variables-by-group-in-one-call)

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(name = c("Aaron Brook", "Arron Afflalo", "Arron Afflalo"), 
                 x = c(450, 980, 236), y = c(36, 25, 25), 
                 a = c(.124, .128, .223), b = c(.530, .597, .621))

df %>% 
   filter(name == "Arron Afflalo") %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   summarize(sum_x = sum(x), sum_y = sum(y), mean_a = mean(a), mean_b = mean(b))
```

If you don't know the names of the columns and just their order, you could also substitute last line with:

```
   summarize(sum_x = sum(.[[2]]), sum_y = sum(.[[3]]), mean_a = mean(.[[4]]), mean_b = mean(.[[5]]))
```

Comment: Could this be a little more general? Arron Afflalo was kinda of an example. My data is hundreds of rows long and I would say 15 or so would be duplicates

Comment: The best would be to give an exemple (or a counter-exemple in this case) but if I understand correctly, you can juste remove the `filter` then you'll have 1 line per name...

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`, if you want a summary for all names and surnames:

```
df %>%
 group_by(V1, V2) %>%
 mutate_at(3:5, funs(sum(.))) %>%
 mutate_at(6:7, funs(mean(.))) %>%
 summarise_all(funs(first(.)))

  V1    V2         V3    V4    V5    V6    V7
  <fct> <fct>   <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Aaron Brook     450    36    25 0.124 0.530
2 Arron Afflalo  1216    50   134 0.176 0.609
```

Or if you want a summary just for that specific name:

```
df %>%
 filter(V1 == "Arron" & V2 == "Afflalo") %>%
 mutate_at(3:5, funs(sum(.))) %>%
 mutate_at(6:7, funs(mean(.))) %>%
 summarise_all(funs(first(.)))

     V1      V2   V3 V4  V5     V6    V7
1 Arron Afflalo 1216 50 134 0.1755 0.609
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Aaron Brook   450 36 25 .124 .530
Arron Afflalo 980 25 40 .128 .597
Arron Afflalo 236 25 94 .223 .621")
```