# function for both mean and Sd based on categorical variable in the data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have 30 Patients with their 100 clinical data such as weight,BMI, waist etc and i want to take mean and SD for all the patients based on their Disease status  For example my data set looks like

```
Patient_id   DateOfBirth       Sex     Weight1   Bmi1   Wasit1  Disease
204065       25-06-1995       Female    113.8    41.3   105.8   0
200214       09-12-1990       Female      90     35.6   108     1
191633       14-09-1971         Male    128.4    47     150     1
186156       22-09-1967         Male    157.3    51.4   145.6   0
```

and i want output  based on  their disease status like

```
Disease weight1Mean  Weight1SD      BMI1Mean    BMI1SD     Waist1Mean  WaistSD  
  0        135           30.7         46.3       7.14       125.7       28.1
  1        109           27.1         41.3       8.06       129         29.7
```

Comment: Possible dupe: [Apply several summary functions on several variables by group in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064202/apply-several-summary-functions-on-several-variables-by-group-in-one-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
your_df %>%
group_by(Disease) %>%
summarize(Weight1Mean = mean(Weight1),
Weight1SD = sd(Weight1)
#Repeat for the rest of variables to summarize
)
```

You can also use `summarize_at` in place of `summarize`:

```
... %>%
summarize_at(vars(Weight1, BMI1, Waist1), list(Mean = mean, SD = sd))
```

Or `summarize_if`:

```
... %>%
summarize_if(is.numeric, list(Mean = mean, SD = sd))
```

If you have numeric variables you want to exclude from summarization, you can recode them as factors or drop them with `select`.

Comment: Thanks for the code but i need all variables Mean and SD and i cannot specify for each  due to 1000 of columns in the dataset any recommendation to get all mean and SD in a single functional output

Comment: @Matrix_32 sorry, I didn't notice 100 variables part: in that case use `summarize_if(is.numeric, list(Mean = mean, SD = sd))`. If you have some numeric values, that you want to exclude from `summarize`, recode them as factors for example.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, .(Weight1Mean = mean(Weight1), Weight1SD = sd(Weight1)), Disease]
```