# aggregate: pass the same function argument twice to FUN

Tags: r, aggregate

Suppose I have some random data:

`year = mpg$year`

`year[mpg$year>2006] = NA`

Now I want to aggregate and use the sum function twice, once with `na.rm = T` and once with `na.rm = F`. Is there a way to pass the same argument twice, once for the first sum call and once for the second (without using `FUN = function(x)`). Something like that:

`aggregate(year, by = list(mpg$model), plyr::each(sum, sum), na.rm = T, na.rm = F)`

Comment: I suggest there is too much ambiguity with that: who is to stay that any other arguments you might provide should go with one or the other or both/all functions?

Comment: Very related: [Apply several summary functions on several variables by group in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/1422451)

Answer (score 2):

Using `mtcars` which is built into R we insert some NA's.

Now using the formula method of `aggregate` set `na.action=na.pass` in `aggregate` to prevent it from automatically removing NA's.  Then use the indicated `Sum` function.

Note that the output of `aggregate`, `a2`, will have two columns where the second column is itself a two column matrix. If we want three columns use `a3 <- do.call("data.frame", a2)` as shown below.

```
mtcars$mpg[1:3] <-  NA # insert some NA's
Sum <- function(x) c(sum1 = sum(x, na.rm = FALSE), sum2 = sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
a2 <- aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars, FUN = Sum, na.action = na.pass); a2
##   cyl mpg.sum1 mpg.sum2
## 1   4       NA    270.5
## 2   6       NA     96.2
## 3   8    211.4    211.4

str(a2)
## 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ cyl: num  4 6 8
##  $ mpg: num [1:3, 1:2] NA NA 211.4 270.5 96.2 ...
##   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
##   .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "sum1" "sum2"

a3 <- do.call("data.frame", a2); a3
   cyl mpg.sum1 mpg.sum2
##   1   4       NA    270.5
##   2   6       NA     96.2
##   3   8    211.4    211.4

str(a3)
## 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ cyl     : num  4 6 8
##  $ mpg.sum1: num  NA NA 211
##  $ mpg.sum2: num  270.5 96.2 211.4
```

Using the data.frame method of `aggregate` is similar except that `na.action` is no longer an argument and NA's are not removed by default.

```
aggregate(mtcars["mpg"], mtcars["cyl"], Sum)
##   cyl mpg.sum1 mpg.sum2
## 1   4       NA    270.5
## 2   6       NA     96.2
## 3   8    211.4    211.4
```

### Alternatives

`collap` from the collapse package is similar to aggregate but does allow a list of functions.  It also supplies `fsum` which defaults to removing NA's.  `summaryBy` in the doBy package also supports a list of functions.  dplyr's `summarize` uses separate arguments instead of a list and data.table can  perform aggregation using its own notation.

```
library(collapse)
collap(mtcars, mpg ~ cyl, c(sum, fsum), keep.col.order = FALSE)
##   cyl sum.mpg fsum.mpg
## 1   4      NA    270.5
## 2   6      NA     96.2
## 3   8   211.4    211.4

library(doBy)
summaryBy(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars, FUN = c(sum, function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)), 
  fun.names = c("sum1", "sum2"))
##   cyl mpg.sum1 mpg.sum2
## 1   4       NA    270.5
## 2   6       NA     96.2
## 3   8    211.4    211.4

library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(sum1 = sum(mpg), sum2 = sum(mpg, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop")
## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##     cyl  sum1  sum2
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     4   NA  270. 
## 2     6   NA   96.2
## 3     8  211. 211. 

library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, .(sum1 = sum(mpg), sum2 = sum(mpg, na.rm = TRUE)), by = cyl]
##    cyl  sum1  sum2
## 1:   6    NA  96.2
## 2:   4    NA 270.5
## 3:   8 211.4 211.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option will be to use `aggregate` in `Map` or `lapply`.

```
x <- mtcars
x$mpg[1:3] <-  NA
```

```
Map(aggregate, list(x$mpg), list(list(x$cyl)), "sum", na.rm=c(TRUE, FALSE))
#[[1]]
#  Group.1     x
#1       4 270.5
#2       6  96.2
#3       8 211.4
#
#[[2]]
#  Group.1     x
#1       4    NA
#2       6    NA
#3       8 211.4
```

```
lapply(list(T=TRUE, F=FALSE), function(y) aggregate(x$mpg, x["cyl"], sum, na.rm=y))
#$T
#  cyl     x
#1   4 270.5
#2   6  96.2
#3   8 211.4
#
#$F
#  cyl     x
#1   4    NA
#2   6    NA
#3   8 211.4
```

Or you create a new `sum` function with different name than `na.rm`.

```
Sum <- function(x, Na.rm, ...) sum(x, na.rm = Na.rm)
aggregate(x$mpg, x["cyl"], plyr::each(sum, Sum), na.rm = TRUE, Na.rm = FALSE)
#  cyl x.sum x.Sum
#1   4 270.5    NA
#2   6  96.2    NA
#3   8 211.4 211.4
```

But personally I would prefer to create a function (but this was not wanted in the question).

```
aggregate(x$mpg, x["cyl"], function(x) c(T = sum(x, na.rm = TRUE), F = sum(x)))
#  cyl   x.T   x.F
#1   4 270.5    NA
#2   6  96.2    NA
#3   8 211.4 211.4
```