# How to group by with min(date) and then filter using data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data.frame “A” in R:

| ID | Interaction.Type | Target.ID | Student | Created.At |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email_sent | 368932 | Isabel Gauss | 10/20/2021 0:02 |
| 1 | email_sent | 370153 | Isabel Gauss | 11/2/2021 0:04 |
| 1 | Open_sent | 375012 | Isabel Gauss | 12/6/2021 22:15 |
| 1 | email_sent | 382353 | Isabel Gauss | 2/3/2022 0:06 |
| 50 | email_sent | 368932 | Jen Gonzalez | 10/20/2021 0:02 |
| 50 | email_sent | 370153 | Jen Gonzalez | 11/2/2021 0:04 |
| 50 | email_sent | 375012 | Jen Gonzalez | 12/6/2021 22:15 |
| 10 | email_sent | 354609 | Isabel Goodwin | 9/23/2021 21:09 |
| 10 | email_sent | 368089 | Isabel Goodwin | 10/20/2021 0:02 |
| 10 | email_sent | 375017 | Isabel Goodwin | 12/5/2021 21:05 |
| 10 | Open_sent | 383095 | Isabel Goodwin | 2/8/2022 1:05 |
| 200 | email_sent | 343546 | Jason Bin | 10/9/2022 21:05 |
| 200 | email_sent | 343543 | Jason Bin | 2/8/2021 1:05 |
| 550 | email_sent | 546354 | Brad pit | 05/29/2023 0:02 |
| 550 | email_sent | 344546 | Brad pit | 10/20/2021 0:02 |
| 550 | email_sent | 343434 | Brad pit | 08/15/2022 0:02 |

And the following integer table “B” in R

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 125 |
| 200 |
| 550 |
| 870 |

I need to group data.frame "A" first to come up with the below:

| ID | Interaction.Type | Student | Min_Created.At |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email_sent | Isabel Gauss | 10/20/2021 0:02 |
| 50 | email_sent | Jen Gonzalez | 10/20/2021 0:02 |
| 11 | email_sent | Isabel Goodwin | 9/23/2021 21:09 |
| 200 | email_sent | Jason Bin | 2/8/2021 1:05 |
| 550 | email_sent | Brad Pit | 10/20/2021 0:02 |

And then filter the above output using the above ID table "B" to come up with the below:

| ID | Interaction.Type | Student | Min_Created.At |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email_sent | Isabel Gauss | 10/20/2021 0:02 |
| 125 | Null | Null | Null |
| 200 | email_sent | Jason Bin | 2/8/2021 1:05 |
| 550 | email_sent | Brad Pit | 10/20/2021 0:02 |
| 870 | Null | Null | Null |

The following is not working:

```
Output_1 <- data.frame(A$ID, A$Interaction.Type == "email_sent", A$Student, Min(A$Created.At), group_by(ID))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, jsaab! Please share your data in a format that is much easier for us to consume (the spaces in your timestamp columns make it a little more challenging. The best is `dput(x)` where `x` is your frame or a subset of the rows and columns (your frame size here is fine, larger data may benefit from subsetting). Inf your desired output, you have the string literal `"Null"`, do you intend for a real-looking string, or would it be better to use R's `NA` to denote no-data-available (among other things)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need the `Created.At` column to be a "real" timestamp; in R, this means a `POSIXt` object. While it's not always true that we cannot work with strings, in this case since "month" is first, sorting and grabbing the minimum of the dates would take more work trying to deal with parsing the string, it's much easier to convert to a timestamp.

```r
dat$Created.At <- as.POSIXct(dat$Created.At, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
head(dat)
#   ID Interaction.Type Target.ID      Student          Created.At
# 1  1       email_sent    368932 Isabel Gauss 2021-10-20 00:02:00
# 2  1       email_sent    370153 Isabel Gauss 2021-11-02 00:04:00
# 3  1        Open_sent    375012 Isabel Gauss 2021-12-06 22:15:00
# 4  1       email_sent    382353 Isabel Gauss 2022-02-03 00:06:00
# 5 50       email_sent    368932 Jen Gonzalez 2021-10-20 00:02:00
# 6 50       email_sent    370153 Jen Gonzalez 2021-11-02 00:04:00
```

From here, the operations are broken down into two things:

- summarize/filter by group, see [Calculate the mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272), [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272), [Apply several summary functions (sum, mean, etc.) on several variables by group in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272)
- merge/join, see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272), [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272)

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  slice_min(Created.At, by = Student) %>%
  left_join(B, ., by = "ID")
#    ID Interaction.Type Target.ID      Student          Created.At
# 1   1       email_sent    368932 Isabel Gauss 2021-10-20 00:02:00
# 2 125             <NA>        NA         <NA>                <NA>
# 3 200       email_sent    343543    Jason Bin 2021-02-08 01:05:00
# 4 550       email_sent    344546     Brad pit 2021-10-20 00:02:00
# 5 870             <NA>        NA         <NA>                <NA>
```

## base R

```r
tmp <- dat[with(dat, ave(as.numeric(Created.At), Student, FUN = function(z) z == min(z))) > 0,]
tmp
#     ID Interaction.Type Target.ID        Student          Created.At
# 1    1       email_sent    368932   Isabel Gauss 2021-10-20 00:02:00
# 5   50       email_sent    368932   Jen Gonzalez 2021-10-20 00:02:00
# 8   10       email_sent    354609 Isabel Goodwin 2021-09-23 21:09:00
# 13 200       email_sent    343543      Jason Bin 2021-02-08 01:05:00
# 15 550       email_sent    344546       Brad pit 2021-10-20 00:02:00
merge(B, tmp, by = "ID", all.x = TRUE)
#    ID Interaction.Type Target.ID      Student          Created.At
# 1   1       email_sent    368932 Isabel Gauss 2021-10-20 00:02:00
# 2 125             <NA>        NA         <NA>                <NA>
# 3 200       email_sent    343543    Jason Bin 2021-02-08 01:05:00
# 4 550       email_sent    344546     Brad pit 2021-10-20 00:02:00
# 5 870             <NA>        NA         <NA>                <NA>
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 200L, 200L, 550L, 550L, 550L), Interaction.Type = c("email_sent", "email_sent", "Open_sent", "email_sent", "email_sent", "email_sent", "email_sent", "email_sent", "email_sent", "email_sent", "Open_sent", "email_sent", "email_sent", "email_sent", "email_sent", "email_sent"), Target.ID = c(368932L, 370153L, 375012L, 382353L, 368932L, 370153L, 375012L, 354609L, 368089L, 375017L, 383095L, 343546L, 343543L, 546354L, 344546L, 343434L ), Student = c("Isabel Gauss", "Isabel Gauss", "Isabel Gauss", "Isabel Gauss", "Jen Gonzalez", "Jen Gonzalez", "Jen Gonzalez", "Isabel Goodwin", "Isabel Goodwin", "Isabel Goodwin", "Isabel Goodwin", "Jason Bin", "Jason Bin", "Brad pit", "Brad pit", "Brad pit"), Created.At = c("10/20/2021 0:02", "11/2/2021 0:04", "12/6/2021 22:15", "2/3/2022 0:06", "10/20/2021 0:02", "11/2/2021 0:04", "12/6/2021 22:15", "9/23/2021 21:09", "10/20/2021 0:02", "12/5/2021 21:05", "2/8/2022 1:05", "10/9/2022 21:05", "2/8/2021 1:05",  "05/29/2023 0:02", "10/20/2021 0:02", "08/15/2022 0:02")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
B <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 125L, 200L, 550L, 870L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: thanks a lot , in fact my date in R is already formated as below "2021-10-20 00:02:08" so I don' tneed I suppose the "POSIXct" function; only when I copy/pasted in word the created.At date I got the following format 10/20/2021 0:02

Comment: can you please elaborate more the base R code since I got the follwoing error "Warning message: In FUN(x) : NAs introduced by coercion" ; maybe because I don't have the exact fileds or number of fields since I have first "Interaction.ID", then "Interaction.Type" then "Target.ID", ID, Student, description and then "Created at"

Comment: I don't know, it works with the data you provided. That kind of problem is common when the "class" of a column is unclear. The best way to get past that ambiguity (when it's a concern) is to use `dput`, as it gives us as close to a binary-duplicate of your real data as possible.