# Aggregate with different functions

Tags: r, aggregate

Looking for a way to aggregate rows with different functions applying to different columns:

```
ID<-c('A','A','A','B','C','D','D','E','E','E')
branch<-c('a','b','c','a','a','a','b','a','b','c')
w <-sample (1:100, 10)
x <-sample (1:100, 10)
y <-sample (1:100, 10)
z <-sample (1:100, 10)
  
tib<-tibble(ID,branch,w,x,y,z)
```

I want to group by ID and use something like aggregate for each row with different branches of the same ID. I want the columns to aggregate differently from each other:

The result should be a single row per ID where rows have been aggregated by:

```
w -> sum
x -> mean
y -> mean
z -> sum
```

Is that possible please?

Comment: Your sample data definition gives a syntax error. Could you please edit it?

Comment: But yes, this is standard with `library(dplyr)` you can  do `tib |> summarize(across(c(w, z), sum), across(c(x, y), mean), .by = your_grouping_column)`

Comment: Related (though not a perfect dupe): https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272