# R dplyr Rowwise sum

Tags: r, dplyr

I have

```
DATA = data.frame(GROUP = c(1,2,1,2,1,2), TIME = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), SCORE = c(0,7,9,8,3,4))
```

and seek to create

```
WANT = data.frame(GROUP = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), TIME = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), SCORE = c(0,7,7,9,8,17,3,4,7))
```

Where for each value of TIME I sum up the SCORE values for all GROUP

I try without success,

```
WANT = DATA %>% group_by(TIME) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(`3' = sum())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest summarize the data and then combine (`bind_rows`) with the original data.

```r
library(dplyr)
DATA %>%
  group_by(TIME) %>%
  summarize(GROUP = max(GROUP)+1, SCORE = sum(SCORE)) %>%
  bind_rows(DATA, .) %>%
  arrange(TIME, GROUP)
#   GROUP TIME SCORE
# 1     1    1     0
# 2     2    1     7
# 3     3    1     7
# 4     1    2     9
# 5     2    2     8
# 6     3    2    17
# 7     1    3     3
# 8     2    3     4
# 9     3    3     7
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the accepted answer, but for those unable or not wanting to use external packages (for whatever reason), for posterity a base R approach could use `tapply` and `rbind`/`cbind` (not I added a 3rd group in the original

```
Want <- rbind(DATA, 
              cbind(GROUP = tapply(DATA$GROUP, DATA$TIME, \(x) max(x)+1), 
                    TIME = seq_along(unique(DATA$TIME)), 
                    SCORE = tapply(DATA$SCORE, DATA$TIME, sum)))
Want <- Want[order(Want$TIME, Want$GROUP),]

#  GROUP TIME SCORE
#      1    1     0
#      2    1     7
#      3    1     7
#      1    2     9
#      2    2     8
#      3    2    17
#      1    3     3
#      2    3     4
#      3    3     7
```

Comment: Good idea to include base R. The "summarize by group" component has other options, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272 (multiple functions).

Answer (score 0):

Note that these only explicitly reference `DATA` once at the top which is consistent with the idea of pipeline flow where the input comes in at top and the output at the bottom.

**1)** Grouping by TIME, set last row of each group appropriately using `group_modify` and `add_row` and then rearrange column order in the `select` to be in the original order.  The `select` statement can be omitted if the order does not matter and the `data.frame` statement can be omitted if a tibble is ok.

```
library(dplyr)

res <- DATA %>%
  group_by(TIME) %>%
  group_modify(~ add_row(., GROUP = max(.$GROUP) + 1, SCORE = sum(.$SCORE))) %>%  
  ungroup %>%
  select(GROUP, TIME, SCORE) %>%
  as.data.frame

identical(res, WANT)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)** Another approach with dplyr is to use `nest_by` and `reframe` in place of `group_modify` and `add_row`.

```
library(dplyr)

res <- DATA %>%
  nest_by(TIME) %>%
  reframe(data = bind_rows(data, summarize(data,
    GROUP = max(GROUP) + 1, SCORE = sum(SCORE)))) %>%
  unnest(data) %>%
  select(GROUP, TIME, SCORE) %>%
  as.data.frame

identical(res, WANT)
## [1] TRUE
```

**3)** Another alternative is to do it column by column:

```
res <- DATA %>%
  group_by(TIME) %>%
  reframe(GROUP = c(GROUP, max(GROUP) + 1), SCORE = c(SCORE, sum(SCORE))) %>%
  select(GROUP, TIME, SCORE) %>%
  as.data.frame

identical(res, WANT)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Update

Simplify.  Add (2) and (3).