# Calculate durations of states and number of state changes from a time series

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, counting, duration

I have a data frame of two columns, one column (Time) contains timestamps from images, the other column (State) contains state shown on the image. These data frames can span several weeks, and have hundreds of rows per day. The "state" in consecutive rows can change, but doesn't have to change.

Example data:

| Time | State |
| --- | --- |
| 20220526173731 | PORED |
| 20220526173741 | PORED |
| 20220526173746 | SJEDI |
| 20220526175242 | PORED |
| 20220526175246 | SJEDI |
| 20220526175806 | SJEDI |
| 20220526175810 | SJEDI |
| 20220526175818 | NEMA |
| 20220526175819 | SJEDI |
| 20220526175819 | SJEDI |
| 20220526175822 | SJEDI |
| 20220526180013 | SJEDI |
| 20220522071053 | NEMA |
| 20220522071056 | NEMA |

What I'd like to do is use R to calculate the duration (in seconds) of each state for the entire period, the duration (in seconds) of each state for each day and the duration (in seconds) of each state before it changes to the next state.
Also, I'd like to calculate the number of times the state changes for the entire period and for each day.

What I did so far:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# input dhe data frame
dat <- read.csv("Lala.csv")


dat$Time <- as.character(dat$Time)
dat$Time <- as.POSIXct(dat$Time, format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S", tz="CET")
dat$Time

dat$State <- as.factor(dat$State)

# give each state run a unique number
setDT(dat)
dat[, state_run := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.integer(dat$State)) != 0L))]
head(dat,20)

# calculate the duration of each state 
dat2 <- dat[, list(StartTime = min(Time),
                     State = State[1],
                     Duration = diff(range(Time))), by = state_run]
```

Unfortunately, this does not give me the duration of each state, it gives me duration from the first row of each state to the last row of each state, which is not the end of the state.
The end of the state if the first row of the next state.

Thank you for any help!

Updating with expected output for the example data:

State duration per day

| Day | State | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-22 | NEMA | 60547 |
| 2022-05-22 | PORED | 0 |
| 2022-05-22 | SJEDI | 0 |
| 2022-05-26 | NEMA | 63452 |
| 2022-05-26 | PORED | 19 |
| 2022-05-26 | SJEDI | 1342 |

Total state durations

| State | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| NEMA | 123999 |
| PORED | 19 |
| SJEDI | 1342 |

Number of state changes per day

| Day | # of State changes |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-22 | 0 |
| 2022-05-26 | 6 |

Comment: (1) Your timestamp does not facilitate accurate time-difference calculation, I urge you to convert it to a `POSIXt`-class object with `as.POSIXct(as.character(Time), format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")` or similar. (2) This sounds very much like "summarize by group", where there are many good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272 (multiple functions). Have you tried any of those?

Comment: If my answer does not accurately reflect the sums that you expect, please provide actual values of your expected output. Thanks!

Comment: NEMA has one "1 sec" duration on 05-26, why is its daily sum 63452 and not 1? Why is the "total state duration" for NEMA not the sum of its durations, instead 123999? And for your state-changes per day, on 05-26 we go from PORED to SJEDI to PORED to SJEDI to NEMA to SJEDI, six states for a total of five state changes.

Comment: On any given time from the first entry to the last entry in the time series a state must exist. So from midnight (morning) on 05-26 until  17:37:31 the state is the one listed in the previous entry. Since the previous entry is "NEMA" (given in the last row of example data on 2022-05-22-07-10-56), the state from 00:00:00 until 17:37:31 is "NEMA" , hence the duration. Likewise there are 6 changes on 05-26, because the day started with the state "NEMA".

Comment: "The end of the state is the first row of the next state." see `?shift` to create a column with the "lead" value

Comment: Exactly, the end of the state is the first row of the next state. I should have emphasized- in chronological order (in time-series order). If a state begins on 05-22, and the next entry is on 05-26 it means that the state is unchanged between these two timestamps. So if we check the duration of the state per day, on day 05-26 it starts at midnight and lasts until the first row with a different state. One solution is to manually input a row at midnight of each day, with the same state as in the previous chronological row, but that is impractical when you have long periods of multiple datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems mostly like simple summaries in `data.table`.

1. I'll convert your `Time` to a `POSIXt` object so that we can rely on time differencing (where some are multi-days ... and while not present here, if anything spans to a different month, your math without this will be wrong).
2. Add `Day`.
3. Order by `Time`, so that we can calculate `diff`, the number of seconds between each row and the next. (The last row is an unknown duration, over to you for the context of how to know how long the last row lasts.)

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(quux)
quux[, Time := as.POSIXct(as.character(Time), format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
     ][, Day := as.Date(Time)]
#                    Time  State        Day
#                  <POSc> <char>     <Date>
#  1: 2022-05-26 17:37:31  PORED 2022-05-26
#  2: 2022-05-26 17:37:41  PORED 2022-05-26
#  3: 2022-05-26 17:37:46  SJEDI 2022-05-26
#  4: 2022-05-26 17:52:42  PORED 2022-05-26
#  5: 2022-05-26 17:52:46  SJEDI 2022-05-26
#  6: 2022-05-26 17:58:06  SJEDI 2022-05-26
#  7: 2022-05-26 17:58:10  SJEDI 2022-05-26
#  8: 2022-05-26 17:58:18   NEMA 2022-05-26
#  9: 2022-05-26 17:58:19  SJEDI 2022-05-26
# 10: 2022-05-26 17:58:19  SJEDI 2022-05-26
# 11: 2022-05-26 17:58:22  SJEDI 2022-05-26
# 12: 2022-05-26 18:00:13  SJEDI 2022-05-26
# 13: 2022-05-22 07:10:53   NEMA 2022-05-22
# 14: 2022-05-22 07:10:56   NEMA 2022-05-22
setorder(quux, Time)
quux[, diff := c(as.numeric(diff(Time), units = "secs"), NA)]
#                    Time  State        Day   diff
#                  <POSc> <char>     <Date>  <num>
#  1: 2022-05-22 07:10:53   NEMA 2022-05-22      3
#  2: 2022-05-22 07:10:56   NEMA 2022-05-22 383195
#  3: 2022-05-26 17:37:31  PORED 2022-05-26     10
#  4: 2022-05-26 17:37:41  PORED 2022-05-26      5
#  5: 2022-05-26 17:37:46  SJEDI 2022-05-26    896
#  6: 2022-05-26 17:52:42  PORED 2022-05-26      4
#  7: 2022-05-26 17:52:46  SJEDI 2022-05-26    320
#  8: 2022-05-26 17:58:06  SJEDI 2022-05-26      4
#  9: 2022-05-26 17:58:10  SJEDI 2022-05-26      8
# 10: 2022-05-26 17:58:18   NEMA 2022-05-26      1
# 11: 2022-05-26 17:58:19  SJEDI 2022-05-26      0
# 12: 2022-05-26 17:58:19  SJEDI 2022-05-26      3
# 13: 2022-05-26 17:58:22  SJEDI 2022-05-26    111
# 14: 2022-05-26 18:00:13  SJEDI 2022-05-26     NA
```

Your summaries:

```r
quux[, sum(diff, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(State)]
#     State     V1
#    <char>  <num>
# 1:   NEMA 383199
# 2:  PORED     19
# 3:  SJEDI   1342
quux[, sum(diff, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(State, Day)]
#     State        Day     V1
#    <char>     <Date>  <num>
# 1:   NEMA 2022-05-22 383198
# 2:  PORED 2022-05-26     19
# 3:  SJEDI 2022-05-26   1342
# 4:   NEMA 2022-05-26      1
quux[, sum(diff, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(rleid(State), State)]
#    rleid  State     V1
#    <int> <char>  <num>
# 1:     1   NEMA 383198
# 2:     2  PORED     15
# 3:     3  SJEDI    896
# 4:     4  PORED      4
# 5:     5  SJEDI    332
# 6:     6   NEMA      1
# 7:     7  SJEDI    114
quux[, sum(State[-1] != State[-.N]), by = Day]
#           Day    V1
#        <Date> <int>
# 1: 2022-05-22     0
# 2: 2022-05-26     5
```

---

Starting data:

```r
quux <- structure(list(Time = c(20220526173731, 20220526173741, 20220526173746, 20220526175242, 20220526175246, 20220526175806, 20220526175810, 20220526175818, 20220526175819, 20220526175819, 20220526175822, 20220526180013, 20220522071053, 20220522071056), State = c("PORED", "PORED", "SJEDI", "PORED", "SJEDI", "SJEDI", "SJEDI", "NEMA", "SJEDI", "SJEDI", "SJEDI", "SJEDI", "NEMA", "NEMA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Comment: Your solution works fine for any dataset that starts and ends in the same day. But as you can see from you output the duration of state "NEMA" on 2022-05-22 is 383198 seconds or over four days. Is it possible somehow to count until midnight, and than for the following day start with the same state from midnight. For example if I have these for rows (2022-05-22 21:00, SJEDI; 2022-05-22 22:00, NEMA; 2022-05-23 06:00, SJEDI; 2022-05-23 08:00, NEMA) it should output: for 2022-05-22 NEMA 7200, SJEDI 3600; and for 2022-05-23 NEMA 21600, SJEDI 3600.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: Thanks! I've added the expected output of example data to the end of the original question.