# Adding total sample sizes to stacked bar charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I'm trying to add sample sizes to the top of my bar charts in ggplot2, but haven't been able to figure out how. I'd like them to read as, for example, *n*=15. Any ideas before I retreat to Photoshop? Here's my code, data and one of the graphs I'd like to label:

[image: Graph]
[image: Spreadsheet]

```
#Load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library('showtext')

#Import data
breadth <- read_excel([Insert file path here])
View(breadth)

#Define scale_fill_manual
cbPalette <- c("#b9503d",
               "#43c9b0")

#Define font
font_add(family = "Arial", regular = "Arial.ttf")

#Enable font
showtext_auto()

ggplot(breadth, aes(fill=breadth, y=count, x=category)) + 
  geom_bar(position='stack', stat='identity') +
  labs(fill='Habitat breadth', x='', y='Number of species') +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial")) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0))) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c('Non-cacher', 'Generalist cacher', 'Specialist cacher'))
```

Here's my `dput(breadth)` output:

```
structure(list(breadth = c("Habitat specialist", "Habitat specialist", 
"Habitat specialist", "Habitat generalist", "Habitat generalist", 
"Habitat generalist"), category = c("Non-cacher", "Non-specialised cachers", 
"Specialised cachers", "Non-cacher", "Non-specialised cachers", 
"Specialised cachers"), count = c(0, 2, 10, 3, 30, 10)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I've tried using the `geom_text` function, but I was only able to add the sample sizes to each division. [image: Graph]

Comment: Welcome to SO, koloeus! Please look at the dupe-links for ways to accomplish what you're hoping to do. This is a good first question! The only piece that would make it easier to help you is sample data. If the dupe-links don't work for you, please [edit] your question, include the output from `dput(breadth)`, explain what didn't work with the other answers, and then @-ping me. From there, we can work through the problem together. Good luck, and again welcome!

Comment: It might be useful to also look at "summarize by group" questions (https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272 (multiple functions)) in order to create a new frame with your group totals, and using that new frame in `geom_text(data=newframe, ...)` for the group totals.

Comment: Hello @r2evans! Thank you very much for the warm welcome and the advice. I've edited my question to include the information you asked for. I looked at the dupe-links before I asked this question, but I wasn't been able to get what I need from them, most likely because I'm not well versed enough in the R language.

Comment: From "summarize by groups", know that you can do `catsums <- aggregate(count ~ category, breadth, FUN = sum)`, which gives the sum of `count` for each `category`. Given that, you can add `geom_text(data = catsums, aes(x=category, y=count, label=count), inherit.aes=FALSE)` to your above `ggplot(...)` expression to add numbers to the top of each column. Does that work?

Comment: @r2evans Adding ```geom_text(data = catsums, aes(x=category, y=count, label=count), inherit.aes=FALSE)``` adds the sample sizes, though they're too close to the bars. Is it possible to add 'n=' and shift them upwards? [Here's what it looks like now.](https://ibb.co/yQh7W7s)

Comment: This is a frequent question for `ggplot2`-questions, look for the use of `vjust=` in the dupe-links (you might be satisfied with `vjust=0` or `vjust=-0.25`) within the call to `geom_text`.

Comment: @r2evans That worked. Thank you very much. Forgive me for repeating myself, but do you know of a way to add n= to each label?

Comment: `label=paste0("n=", count)` or use `aggregate(count ~ category, breadth, FUN = function(z) paste0("n=", sum(z)))`

Comment: @r2evans Replacing ```label=count``` with ```label=paste0("n=", count)``` worked! Thank you! Is it possible to italicise the n, or would that get a bit too complicated?

Comment: Yes. Create a summary frame with `catsums <- aggregate(count ~ category, breadth, FUN = sum) |> transform(lbl = paste("italic(n) ==", count))`, then use `geom_text(data = catsums, aes(x=category, y=count, label = lbl), inherit.aes=FALSE, vjust=0, parse=TRUE)`. See `?plotmath` for things like `italic(n)`, and feel free to search the rest of SO for questions on "subscript/superscript/italics/bold" in ggplot graphics. Once you know how to do any of that, the rest just fall into place.

Comment: That worked perfectly. You're an absolute legend. Thank you so much for your help (and patience)!