# Calculate the mean of the rows whereby values in a specific column is duplicated

Tags: r

For all the rows whereby the `gene_id` column is the same, take the mean of the remaining columns (i.e., numeric columns). Keep only one row per `gene_id`.

Attempt:

```
bval <- aggregate(bval[2:ncol(bval),], list(bval[,"gene_id"]), mean)
```

Traceback:

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Input:

```
> dput(bval[1:5,1:5])
structure(c("WASH7P", "AL669831", "AL669831", "AL669831", "LINC01128", 
"0.937221863875433", "0.884685944584618", "0.00772875906060839", 
"0.974299336034647", "0.527647691683903", "0.820402509764824", 
"0.746851906366392", "0.00688133381821596", "0.955114652587149", 
"0.838526921251755", "0.856636409601063", "0.832976487385604", 
"0.0100358136497527", "0.980061730438325", "0.977217882552452", 
"0.943360790700266", "0.884748613341517", "0.0130798750757149", 
"0.989522013973257", "0.971365584092397"), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("cg13869341", "cg15560884", "cg01014490", "cg17505339", 
    "cg16736630"), c("gene_id", "TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01")))
```

Comment: plase share an example output so we can understand your needs a little better

Comment: You may be struggling with object classes here. This object is an array/matrix, but it clearly contains characters (the geneID column) and numeric columns. Matrix will only accept a single class, so in this case the numbers were coerced to strings. I suspect you may have inadvertently coerced a data.frame or tibble into a matrix upstream. I would start by correcting that, before diving into the current question.

Comment: Once you fix the problem identified by GuedesBF (using `as.numeric`), this is a duplicate of a number of questions that focus on "summarize by group": https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272 (multiple functions).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

bval %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column() %>% group_by(gene_id) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with('TCGA'), ~ mean(as.numeric(.x))))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  gene_id   TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01
  <chr>               <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1 AL669831            0.622           0.570           0.608           0.629
2 LINC01128           0.528           0.839           0.977           0.971
3 WASH7P              0.937           0.820           0.857           0.943
```

###### alternatively if you still wish to use the aggregate function and dont wish to convert the character to numeric , but still wish to get the expected results, purrr package offers an interesting function compose where we can include multiple functions, so the values go to every function, in the compose the functions work from right to left. so in our case we wish to convert the character values to numeric first followed by mean

```r
fn <- purrr::compose(\(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), \(x) as.numeric(x))
```

###### we can then use this `fn` in the aggregate functioin, however we need to convert the data to a dataframe from matrix/array

```r
bval3 <- bval %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column()

aggregate(bval3[,3:ncol(bval3)], list(gene_id=bval3[["gene_id"]]), fn)


    gene_id TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01
1  AL669831       0.6222380       0.5696160       0.6076913       0.6291168
2 LINC01128       0.5276477       0.8385269       0.9772179       0.9713656
3    WASH7P       0.9372219       0.8204025       0.8566364       0.9433608
```

Answer (score 0):

jkatam's answer (and likely a popular method, one which I generally agree with) assumes you want to and are able to convert back to a frame for your summaries. If that's what you want, then see:

- [Calculate the mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272),
- [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272), and
- [Apply several summary functions (sum, mean, etc.) on several variables by group in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272) (with multiple functions)

If you must (for whatever reason) work on this data as a matrix, however, then continue below.

GuedesBF has identified a clear problem with your data. As a `matrix`, this problem is quite doable in its current form, but I *strongly* recommend you fix the code that put you into this broken situation. If you truly need your data as a `matrix` (which is perfectly fine), then I suggest you *preserve* your `gene_id` column before converting to a matrix; this can be saved either as an external object (not recommended) or preferably as row names of the original matrix.

Up front, I'll assume you will go back and fix your errant/broken code so that you don't have to convert back to numbers.

Data:

```r
bval_fixed <- matrix(as.numeric(bval[,-1]), nrow=5, ncol=4, byrow=FALSE) |>
  `rownames<-`(bval[,1])
bval_fixed
#                  [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
# WASH7P    0.937221864 0.820402510 0.85663641 0.94336079
# AL669831  0.884685945 0.746851906 0.83297649 0.88474861
# AL669831  0.007728759 0.006881334 0.01003581 0.01307988
# AL669831  0.974299336 0.955114653 0.98006173 0.98952201
# LINC01128 0.527647692 0.838526921 0.97721788 0.97136558

## raw data for reproduction here:
bval_fixed <- structure(c(0.937221863875433, 0.884685944584618, 0.00772875906060839, 0.974299336034647, 0.527647691683903, 0.820402509764824, 0.746851906366392, 0.00688133381821596, 0.955114652587149, 0.838526921251755, 0.856636409601063, 0.832976487385604, 0.0100358136497527, 0.980061730438325, 0.977217882552452, 0.943360790700266, 0.884748613341517, 0.0130798750757149, 0.989522013973257, 0.971365584092397), dim = 5:4, dimnames = list(c(cg13869341 = "WASH7P", cg15560884 = "AL669831", cg01014490 = "AL669831",  cg17505339 = "AL669831", cg16736630 = "LINC01128"), NULL))
```

(Again, fix the code that gets you here, I don't think you should focus on using `as.numeric`.)

```r
out <- tapply(1:nrow(bval_fixed), rownames(bval_fixed),
              FUN = function(z) colMeans(bval_fixed[z,,drop=FALSE])) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _)
out
#                [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# AL669831  0.6222380 0.5696160 0.6076913 0.6291168
# LINC01128 0.5276477 0.8385269 0.9772179 0.9713656
# WASH7P    0.9372219 0.8204025 0.8566364 0.9433608
```

Answer (score 0):

Take note that you do have a matrix and not a dataframe. Matrices only store one data type. So far you have characters. To obtain the mean, you will have to convert these to numeric.

---

#### Using `tapply`:

```
tapply(as.numeric(bval[,-1]),list(bval[row(bval[,-1]),1],col(bval[,-1])),mean)
                  1         2         3         4
AL669831  0.6222380 0.5696160 0.6076913 0.6291168
LINC01128 0.5276477 0.8385269 0.9772179 0.9713656
WASH7P    0.9372219 0.8204025 0.8566364 0.9433608
```

---

#### Using `aggregate`

```
cbind(gene = bval[,1],type.convert(data.frame(bval[,-1]), as.is = TRUE))|>
   aggregate(.~gene, mean)

       gene TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01
1  AL669831       0.6222380       0.5696160       0.6076913       0.6291168
2 LINC01128       0.5276477       0.8385269       0.9772179       0.9713656
3    WASH7P       0.9372219       0.8204025       0.8566364       0.9433608
```