# Extract all genes for unique Sample in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataframe of samples and genes associates with each gene. I need to extract all genes associated with each sample into a dataframe.

| Sample | Genes |
| --- | --- |
| A | Gene1 |
| A | Gene2 |
| B | Gene3 |
| B | Gene2 |
| C | Gene3 |
| B | Gene1 |
| C | Gene4 |

I need to create a dataframe like below.

| Sample | Genes |
| --- | --- |
| A | Gene1, Gene2 |
| B | Gene3, Gene2, Gene1 |
| C | Gene3, Gene4 |

What's the best possible way to do this?

Comment: Try `aggregate(Genes ~ Sample, df, unique)`, not sure about the desired output though. Maybe you could add that to your question. Also, normally it's quasi-required to show the code you're struggling with to avoid allegations you're using this platform as a coding service.

Comment: There must be dupes of this.

Comment: @Friede well, there are https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272 (multiple functions), but I don't see many questions that choose to string-combine data very often ... but it's not rare, perhaps there are better questions.

Comment: For the OP, for your expected output, are you hoping for list-columns or for a single string per row, e.g., `"Gene1, Gene2"`? Both are valid depending on what you will be doing with it later; if this is solely for "rendering" and report generation, then single-strings per row should suffice, but if you're going to do continued data-munging with it  later in your processing, then I suggest having them as list-columns might prove useful.

Comment: What is missing from @AndreWildberg's suggestion?

Comment: yes I need to do further data processing where I need find each of these genes in another dataframe. I was thinking to put the list of genes -    df %>% filter(Genes %in% list_i_got_from_this)

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
library(dplyr)


data <- data.frame(
Sample = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C'),
Genes = c('Gene1', 'Gene2', 'Gene3', 'Gene2', 'Gene3',    'Gene1', 'Gene4')
)

 result <- data %>%
 group_by(Sample) %>%
  summarize(Genes = list(unique(Genes)))
```

Comment: Why so complicated and verbose? There is no explicit `dplyr`-tag.

Comment: @Friede just because a tag isn't listed doesn't mean it isn't a valid suggestion.